# JavaScript != Java

Tags: discussion, tags

Lately I've been doing a lot of work with Java and JavaScript through Java ScriptEngine and every time I come to a question about the two someone feels the need to answer the question with, *"Java and JavaScript are two different languages. They have nothing in common!"* or *"Just because the word Java is in JavaScript doesn't mean its Java"* or *"Java != JavaScript"*.

Well OK... That doesn't answer the question and **it is so irrelevant** because you can obviously use Java inside of JavaScript and you can use JavaScript inside of Java so just because someone is asking a question about the two doesn't mean they think they're are the same language.

So my question is how come so many people seem to get worked up over the fact someone is trying to use Java and JavaScript together and will dismiss the question with their condescending phrases instead of offering a solution?

Here is an example,

```
var SwingGui = JavaImporter(Packages.javax.swing,
                    Packages.javax.swing.event,
                    Packages.javax.swing.border,
                    java.awt.event,
                    java.awt.Point,
                    java.awt.Rectangle,
                    java.awt.Dimension);
...

with (SwingGui) {
    var mybutton = new JButton(test);
    var mypoint = new Point(10, 10);
    var myframe = new JFrame();
    ...
}
```

sources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/scripting-140262.html

Comment: Because the answerers are weary of clueless users who don't know the difference.  Solution: demonstrate in your question that you know the difference, and downvote answers from people who answered based on seeing [java][javascript] tags rather than reading the question.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot down vote but thanks for the advice. I do feel like they don't read the question and make their remarks just by the two tags because I'll get comments seconds/minutes after my posts on the two subjects.

Comment: I'd recommend not tagging your question as [tag:javascript]. Despite the fact that you're running JavaScript in Java via a `ScriptEngine`, an answer would be related to specifics of the `ScriptEngine` in Java, rather than JavaScript.

Comment: All technical vocabulary aside, what I mean is I am doing the following. I use Java classes inside JavaScript, where the JavaScript is being evaluated from Java Script Engine (So not in a browser or on the internet). Now vice versa I can embed JavaScript in a string, or just call it from a file with .js extension, and use the JavaScript code inside Java by using Script Engine. So yes, in my mind you can use Java inside of JavaScript and yes you can use JavaScript inside of Java.

Comment: @Qantas 94 Heavy OK, that is good to know. I'm an up and coming StackOverflow member still learning the ropes.

Comment: Another similar problem is the confusion of [tag:bootstrap] and [tag:twitter-bootstrap]. I added the "not to be confused with" notice on bootstrap, but not many new users read the excerpt.

Comment: There is absolutely no way you can use java within javascript. If you think you do, then that's not javascript.

Comment: @Umur Kontacı Sure you can I'm doing it right now. Read this, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java or check out my update #2 to see how.

Comment: @Umur Kontacı In fact you can do it with any JSR-223 language. That means you can use Python in Java and Java in Python as long as you have Jython! To be clear if you know Python you know Jython, if you know Jython you know Python ;)

Comment: I wish I could upvote the original question a billion times.

Comment: Wow!  I learned something new... (Didn't know that you could use Java within JavaScript!) `:D`

Comment: @anorton Sure can. But keep in mind the context in which I'm using it in. As in I'm not using it on the internet. From my research, I've heard its possible to use Java on the internet in your JavaScript but I think the client would need Java installed and at any rate the JVM may slow things down at first. Again I'm using JavaScript through the Java Script Engine API.

Comment: @codeMonkey That's javascript within java. It's even called scripting java. What I said was you cannot use java in javascript.

Comment: @Umur Kontacı But its Java within JavaScript. Even for my current project I have JavaScript files with the extension .js that are using classes I created in Java. Can you explain why this is not JavaScript using Java?

Comment: @codeMonkey: Don't downvote, it costs you reputation (As a new user it's unfair to you). Just flag the answers for being ignorant.

Comment: My question here went from an up vote of 12 then down to 9. Is it because I keep editing it? I added some notes of information based off the comments everyone has left, but after I did that I lost two points, so then I took the two updates off to go back to my original question and now I have lost even more points. Is this people taking back their up votes?

Comment: @codeMonkey It is at least as likely to be due to new downvotes from people who had not viewed the question before. I thought the sample code improved the question, but that is only one opinion. Maybe add the paragraph I suggested in my answer?

Comment: I've also seen these comments on GWT questions, where you can write native JavaScript code that directly uses code written in Java.

Comment: Why nobody is bothering to tag properly or at least fix the tags?

Comment: `Notification: I'm using Java and JavaScript together. Yes, Java != JavaScript. But I need to use it here. PLEASE DON'T TELL ME ABOUT JAVA != JAVASCRIPT AGAIN!`

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan Thanks I think you're right I liked having the example in there to show people it is possible. I put it back in.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Wouldn't you agree, though, it's huge a waste of time and restriction on learning to force users to overcompensate for the "wariness" of other users?  Ideally, you have the shortest-possible question and the shortest-possible answer, right?  This in-following with the minimum-information principle, helps people to retain the information.  It also allows answerers to quickly get on to the answering.  As per 'wary' people, they tend to think people are stupid: how intelligent can they themselves be to make such a basic error, and why cater to them if they prioritize slamming you?

Comment: Stack Overflow's two biggest problems: 1) Low quality questions. 2) People building "defences" against low quality questions.

Comment: You should comment back and tell them to add type safety: `JavaScript !== Java`

Comment: Wow, `Java Script Engine`. Such a horrible name. They couldn't think of a better name

Comment: Let's be clear.. You cannot use Java code from within JavaScript. You can, however, use Mozilla's LiveConnect to bridge JavaScript and Java but your Java code is not living within JavaScript. It is an applet. A lot of people use AJAX to communicate back to a JSP. Java in this case would be the server side language and JavaScript would be the client side. You can use JavaScript in Java through the ScriptEngine, but its convenience.

Comment: Do you have good examples? Using JS in pair with Java is fine, but 95% of the time it really is the OP not knowing what language is what.

Comment: In my opinion, Java and JavaScript have plenty ... well, enough ... in common. Yes, it is a misnomer, because JavaScript should just be called ECMA script. But, syntatically, they are similar. From an object perspective, they are similar. The fact that every object is either a primitive or a pointer is similar.  If you know Java, learning JavaScript is not difficult (though I cannot speak for the other way around). Yes, the two languages have entirely different purposes, but just because Java != JavaScript doesn't mean they have nothing in common. The two are more alike than C/C++/Python/Perl.

Comment: @codeMonkey: that's not Java in JavaScript. That's using script syntax through the ScriptEngine in Java. Aka, it's not JavaScript and should not be tagged with JavaScript. It should be tagged Java and then scriptengine.

Comment: But it's still Java. It's in script syntax

Comment: @codeMonkey: I know what it is. It's not JavaScript Engine. It's JavaScript Script Engine. There is a difference in the naming. From Oracle: "JavaAdapter is the feature by which a Java class can be extended by JavaScript and Java interfaces may be implemented by JavaScript.". It's Java implemented in JavaScript syntax to be interpreted by the JavaScript Script Engine in Java. It cannot standalone as simple JavaScript therefore, you should tag it Java and ScriptEngine or if there is a javascript-script-engine tag use that. It is not JavaScript. If you cannot use it without the engine.

Comment: Finally, you need the Engine to interpret it. I understand it won't be used in the browser. It was designed for rapid prototyping without the need for all the class files and what not. But you can't use that proprietary JavaScript in a browser. That tag was not designed for what you are trying to do and tagging it with JavaScript will just confuse people. So to stop confusing people, just use the Java and ScriptEngine or other related ScriptEngine tag. Trying to make your life easier. Heck, if you insist, then tag it with Rhino.

Comment: @codeMonkey: That's correct. For instance, there would be no need to tag windows if you are doing C# development. It's irrelevant.

Comment: (Java != JavaScript) === false; ....................
(Java !== JavaScript) === true;

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Criticism of tags should not be posted as an answer; users should be either commenting, or, preferably, correcting the tags themselves.

Since the two languages' tags are generally grazed upon by different groups of users, *and* since the confusion of the two is a problem that's been happening for a very long time, tempers are set off. Unfortunately, this just ends up taking more moderation.

Comment: And this case is more niche than the rookie confused tagging; so it's not wrong to 'optimise' this way around.

Comment: Answers with what is not an answer should not be posted neither xD

Answer (score 55):

> how come so many people seem to get worked up over the fact someone is trying to use Java and JavaScript together and will dismiss the question with their condescending phrases instead of offering a solution?

Put yourself in the mind of an unenlightened developer for a moment, who has never heard of "Java ScriptEngine". They will probably presume "Java ScriptEngine" was just a typo and what you really meant was "JavaScript Engine".

Now, take a look at the first two sentences of one of your recent posts, envisioning their perspective:

Taking a look at one of your most recent questions, as an example I suspect it's your wording that's getting unenlightened developers worked up:

> I need to use classes from a jar file inside JavaScript. I'm using JavaScript through Java ScriptEngine"

They've never heard of using Java from JavaScript. They have seen tens if not hundreds of noob posts where people totally mix up the technologies. "Jar inside JavaScript? Dude...you got your technologies mixed up" is what they would be thinking after the first sentence. Then they get to the second sentence and just assume you have no idea what you're talking about, because it sounds kind of garbled if you haven't heard of ScriptEngine

How could you make a question like that more clear? Start off my explaining that you are using Java AND Javascript, or be more wordy and say things like "Java Jar File" to make it more clear that it's obvious to you that Jar = Java and it's not just an "I'm mixed up" noob question.

For example,

> "I need to use classes from a *Java* jar file inside some JavaScript
>   code. I'm using JavaScript in my Java app through *Java ScriptEngine*"

or maybe,

> "I have a hybrid program that uses both Java and Javascript via `Java
>   ScriptEngine`. Inside the JavaScript portion of my code, I need to use
>   classes from a jar file..."

or

> "I realize Java != JavaScript. I'm using Java and Javascript together
>   using Java ScriptEngine. I need to use a class from my Jar file from
>   the Javascript portion...."

I could be butchering what you're trying to say, or what you're trying to do, but hopefully you understand what I'm getting at, that your question would be confusing to someone who has never heard of "ScriptEngine" and didn't go google scriptengine when they saw the tagwiki for that tag was blank (perhaps you could suggest an edit for that tag's tagwiki as well).

I will say, writing good questions is HARD. I've been around for several years on stackoverflow and I still sometimes write bad questions--or a good question with a bad subject line causing unnecessary downvotes, etc. It takes practice, and sometimes editing or feedback from others to understand their perspective about why questions are good or bad.

Comment: Thanks for the advice you make some good points. Also I did not know the tagwiki for ScriptEngine was blank; I'm new to the community by the way.

Comment: I just submitted a suggested edit to the tagwiki for that tag to try to clarify what it is (though not to say that couldn't be improved upon by someone who's actually *used* the ScriptEngine before. When you mouseover the tags it will usually give a brief description of the tag. Not everyone will take the time to read that, but it does help when you aren't sure if you have the right tag or are curious what a tag is about.

Comment: Could anyone submit information for the tagwiki. I may not be qualified but I have been working a lot with the ScriptEngine API this past month and could certainly write a brief description.

Comment: Even I don't have enough reputation to edit the tag directly and it has to go to the review queue to be approved by a higher rep user. If you click on the tag it pops up the tag wiki for the tag and has links to edit Here's what I submitted already for that tag: "Java's ScriptEngine system allows you to run/evaluate statements written in other programming languages like Javascript/ECMAScript, Python/Jython, and Tcl/Jacl."

Comment: There is space to add a detailed description as well, but I didn't fill anything in there since I'm not an expert on those technologies ;-)

Comment: That is good. Specifically they must be JSR-223.

Comment: Additional recommendation: make "Java ScriptEngine" a hyperlink to the documentation for this software.  That both proves you didn't misspell it, and offers enlightenment to people who haven't heard of it before.

Comment: @Zack That is genius! I like that solution.

Comment: By the way, it's JavaScript Script Engine. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/#jsengine

Comment: That second quote is perfectly clear already. Anyone with enough confidence to get angry about people confusing javascript and java should themselves know enough about both to realize the statement "I'm using JavaScript through Java ScriptEngine" makes complete and perfect sense. The fact that they get worked up implies they know little about Java and are unqualified to lash someone else with misappropriated aggression. It's a common problem, people with poor reading comprehension skim over a question and flip to hostility, then make personal insults when you downvote them for not reading.

Comment: Unfortunately I've seen this kind of behavior from 50K+ users, I'd cite examples but their personal insults were deleted by moderators.

Comment: @AaronLS, While I haven't used Java lately, I used it extensively in college and I've also used quite a bit of JavaScript. I, probably like most Java devs, never had any reason to want to use JavaScript inside a Java program, so I had never heard of Java's ScriptEngine. As such, I can definitely understand how someone who had a reasonably deep understanding of Java would have read the sentences quoted in this answer and thought the asker didn't know the difference between Java and JavaScript.

Comment: When you have libraries as extensive as those in Java and .NET and languages that get used for a huge variety of purposes, as with Java and C#, it's completely normal for even very experienced developers using those languages to be unfamiliar with significant parts of the API.

Comment: @reirab You have made factual statements but that doesn't negate the inexcusable behavior of some people. There is a distinction between not knowing about an API, versus acting like they know everything and personally insulting others on account of blind ignorance.

Comment: @reirab My own experience has been the more I've learned over the years reveals more on the horizon that I am aware that I don't know.  Thus if anything, more experience should == more humbleness.  But for some, they can't see that horizon of things yet unlearned, and all they exude is arrogance.

Comment: @codeMonkey: it wouldn't be correct because that's not what Oracle calls it and they are the canonical source

Comment: @codeMonkey: it's in the link above. If using Ruby, then it would be the Ruby ScriptEngine. But since it is JavaScript, it is the JavaScript Scriptengine. I didn't make the name up.

Comment: @codeMonkey: you call it what you want but if it was so clear you wouldn't have started this meta post

Comment: @staticx actually, to be precise, it is `Java JavaScript Script Engine` or `Javas JavaScript Script Engine` ;)

Comment: @AaronLS, I agree with you there. I was just saying I could understand how an experienced Java dev could have reached the conclusion mentioned in Jessica's answer. Condescending to the person asking the question definitely isn't excusable, but I can understand how even a rather experienced dev would mistakenly arrive at the conclusion that the person asking the question was yet another of the hundreds or more people that they've heard confuse Java and JavaScript.

Comment: The second wording suggestion ("I have a hybrid program that uses both Java and Javascript via Java ScriptEngine. Inside the JavaScript portion of my code, I need to use classes from a jar file...") is very good.

Answer (score 23):

In addition to Mooseman's answer, consider the following:

Write, and edit carefully, a short background information paragraph describing what you are doing, including the tools you are using. Put that at the start of each question for which this might be an issue.

Comment: I think some people just aren't reading everything I write. They see the tags or title and see Java with JavaScript and jump straight to their conclusions.

Comment: @codeMonkey I'm hoping they at least read the first sentence or two, so making that a carefully written background may help.

Comment: @codeMonkey, you can think that, and behave as if it's true, or you can *try* to mitigate it by posting a notice, and then you'll know for certain.

Comment: or tag it with rhino and then everyone will know for certain what it is

Comment: +1 Background is very important. I have had to edit my questions over and over because I see how easily they would result in wrong interpretation. Background or sample code makes it instantly clearer.It has long been "fashionable" for some to angrily proclaim that "Java != JavaScript" from the time JavaScript was created. People have inherited that and its almost knee-jerk(for them). I believe with the right question, you can get quicker questions in optimal time. Than one where you will still clarify what you mean. So best get it over to begin with. Next best thing to a picture, is an example