# Allow for Tag Antonyms

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonym-process

This is a fairly young idea, but I'd love to see some way of implementing "tag antonyms" in addition to synonyms. They wouldn't be strictly enforced, but for instance, if a user typed both [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) and [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), it could pop up and give the definition of each, suggesting that user reconsider. It's just that I see a lot of people tagging their MySQL- or Oracle-related questions with [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) even though it specifically says in its preview definition that it's for use purely with Microsoft's SQL Server.  I correct them when I come across them, but it'd lighten the load on reviewers and probably get people better answers faster.

There are times, I'm sure, when you might legitimately want to include both tags, so again it should only be a passive warning system. It'd just be nice to have *something*, because I'm sure very few of these mean to tag maliciously. An example of a time when this would need to be passive is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726678/migrate-big-tables-from-mysql-to-mssql), where there's clearly good reason to tag both.

I haven't noticed other examples personally, so maybe this is a super isolated topic, where the tag-name of [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) just confuses people innately others don't, but it seems like the kind of thing that would pop up here and there with other tags, and again it would just serve to organize the site better and help people get better answers.

Although it could also be nice on versions. For instance, and this is a SQL Server question but it could just as easily be anything else, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719074/when-to-rebuild-and-when-to-reorganize-indexes) has all the versions of SQL Server tagged, even though the question is really just about SQL Server in general.

And I suppose it hadn't really occurred to me when I first wrote this, but there *are* strange times when you come across people who just tag every language they can think of. "Oh, I'm asking a question about C#? Well, anyone who knows C++ should be able to answer that! [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)" and it's just silly. I'm not sure whether a warning would actually deter people from doing that, but it could help. And here I am a couple hours later noticing [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252430/disallow-the-tagging-of-questions-with-both-c-and-c-tags?rq=1).

---

I've seen a ton of these particular cases today. This one wasn't the exact same, in fact this feature wouldn't even have helped, but it's a good, extreme example. I saw a post wherein a person asking about computed column syntax. She tagged her post with [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), and I believe it was [concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concatenation) (she wanted to have a computed column that concatenated two other fields, but that's not my point). I answered her question within a minute of posting with the proper syntax for T-SQL, since I assumed that's what she was referring to with that tag. She tried it and got an error, and the only way I even came to the knowledge that she was using anything other than SQL Server was when she gave me the error text and it looked nothing like something SQL would say. When I asked her the edition, she said "SQL Developer 4.[something]," and when I looked that number up it brought me straight to Oracle's site. After learning she was using Oracle SQL Developer, that made it a whole lot easier to, you know, use the syntax of the language we were actually talking about.

Now, again, that's not a great example for here (the great examples are a lot less climactic, since it's really more of a head-banging "really? Are you really using [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) AND [oracle-sqldeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-sqldeveloper) at the same time? Or do you just not read tag descriptions?" moments). But you can see how this could be a useful feature to have in there. Just some sort of test to make sure the person actually knows that they're tagging things that don't make sense together. Perhaps I'm just [moving for a tag renaming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262934/rename-sql-server-tag-to-ms-sql-server) of [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) to [ms-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-sql-server) or something like that. But I do think there are other applications a feature like this could have.

---

**Edit:**

Oh hey, a day later, after all that, I just came across [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207274/suggested-tags-both-sql-server-and-mysql-are-suggested-by-the-system). I had looked around for something on SO Meta, but it didn't occur to be to check *SE* Meta. I still think this deserves some support, though. It'd be such a useful feature, particularly for new users, and I think as far as feature implementations go, it'd be relatively "easy" to do.

Comment: You mean identify tags that very probably are falsely used together? Well one could maybe evaluate all the tag edits and have a look at those tags that are removed later and define them as false friends and warn when using them together.

Comment: This could also be seen as an argument to [rename the `sql-server` tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262934/rename-sql-server-tag-to-ms-sql-server)..

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  Maybe to ***MS-SQL-Server*** or something like that.

Comment: @wallyk: note that that discussion has been had before, and the comments here is not the place for it.

Comment: I would love to see this for [tag:c] and [tag:c++].

Comment: This could also be seen as an argument to give tag suggestions after the user has typed the question, based on the text of the question.

Comment: @CodingMash I don't think that'd hurt, but I can still imagine people going in and manually adding other, unknowingly unrelated tags to it. Unless it was an overwhelmingly powerful and trustworthy system for suggestions (and I've never seen one), people would think they were better at it than the system and they'd go around it. But I've also seen cases where people have referred to "SQL" in their MySQL-related questions and *not* MySQL, and a tag-suggestion system would simply enforce their incorrect decisions.  But that all said, even as a marginally experienced user I'd love such a feature.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I do not think that [SQL] and [MySQL] are excluding each other. I'd say that with knowledge of [SQL] one could answer [MySQL] questions about queries.

Comment: @Theolodis that largely depends on the complexity of the issue. Many problems for which that's true could be easily answered by a search of the web, and consequently wouldn't be appropriate here anyway. And even so, tags should be used to categorize questions, not find people who can answer your question. By that logic, it'd be acceptable to tag a C# question with [C++], since *most* people who know C++ could probably figure out C#. But that hardly seems reasonable.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen [SQL] and [MYSQL] go well together. I'm primary a Postgres person and still happen to know a lot about mysql, ms-sql, oracle, db2 etc. So I follow [sql] but not [mysql] and not every mysql problem is sql related, think about administration or connection issues.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer [SQL], yes. MySQL is a form of SQL, and I have no problem with people tagging [MySQL] and [SQL]. It is not, however, the same as [Sql-Server]. The [Sql-Server] tag is meant to indicate Microsoft's SQL Server. They (Microsoft) likely could have come up with name that would be less confusing, but that doesn't mean they're congruent. It's a matter of principle, if nothing else. But in any event, that was an example. As you can see, other people have brought up the difference between C and C++.

Comment: [java] and [javascript]. Nuff said.

Comment: Something I frequently encounter [bootstrap] and [twitter-bootstrap]

Comment: Would also be nice to flag tags that *can* go together, but are often used together incorrectly. For example, I've seen many questions about [objective-c], [cocoa], or [ios] development that also include the [xcode] tag, even though the question has nothing to do with the IDE.

Comment: [mathematical-optimization] and [optimization] are another issue that this could help with.

Comment: I think the maintenance of tag antonyms will quickly become cumbersome. We'll still have to deal with people ignoring the warning (either because they don't care, or think their case is an exception) and still have the manual task of tag cleanup. On top of that, someone has to maintain all the antonyms. We can hit a few of the common ones, but there are tons of tags that should rarely, if ever, be seen together. Name any two frameworks for different languages (say, [django] and [ruby-on-rails]). I don't want to maintain that. :)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Have you seen this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262693/javascript-java ?

Comment: @user11153 I have, which is why antonyms wouldn't be blocking, merely advising.

Comment: I think this will strike a clairvoyance problem.  In some cases you might want to ask a question along the lines of 'My linked server has permission issues connecting from SQL Server to MySQL' [tag:mysql] [tag:sql-server] [tag:linked-server].

Comment: Another example of where tag antonyms would be useful - I've started seeing questions tagged [spring] (Java framework) and [boot] (system boot), when asking questions about "Spring Boot", which looks like a configuration helper framework for the former.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320873/are-tags-mutability-and-immutability-the-same

Answer (score -13):

I don't think it is safe to make any assumptions about what can and cannot exist together. I see a comment suggesting [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) as a candidate, as if to propose that the two languages are mutually exclusive. They are not. Even if one is not able to conceive of a use case, it is simple arrogance to assume that no one is using a technology or language in a way that you cannot conceive of.

Tags are representative of concepts that are very difficult to describe in clear enough terms to warrant mutual exclusivity, from a systems perspective. This is the sort of concept that is best handled by human minds, and as it happens, we have a large pool of content editors/moderators to do just that. I don't think such a change would be very constructive to the process here.

Comment: I wasn't the person who voted this down, but what you're saying is why I said that it should only be a *suggestion*. For instance a popup that just says "hey, we see you tagged java and javascript. That's not a typical case. Are you sure you meant to do that?" I would definitely not suggest we have it strictly enforced, particularly as I posed the example of a person asking to move data from MySQL to SQL Server. That's a good time to tag both as well. I just suspect most of the times all these are tagged together, it's unknowingly erroneous by the asker.