# Tag combinations that suggest re-tagging automatically

Tags: feature-request, tags

In the tag I answer in primarily, [sas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sas), many of the questions are about the SAS macro language, [sas-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sas-macro).  However, well over half of the questions asked about that are tagged [sas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sas)[macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macro), which is understandable, but requires a lot of silly editing on my part.

It would be helpful if we could set up something similar to synonym, where either an automatic conversions happens when two tags are used together, or a tooltip pops up to suggest a "Do you mean...".  This would be similar to someone using [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)[script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) for example and having it automatically convert (or suggest) [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)[query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query) changing the latter to [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql)[server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server) -> [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), etc.

Comment: it definitely shouldn't automatically convert.

Comment: @ChrisF: What about the *much more reasonable* auto-suggest? (Would still be a new feature which is quite some work)

Comment: @Deduplicator - The auto-suggest does seem to be a more reasonable suggestion.

Comment: Why would `Javascript` and `query` become `jQuery`?

Comment: @Theolodis [tag:Javascript]+[tag:query] should become [tag:Javascript]+[tag:Jquery].  I'm assuming [tag:query] is either a pointless tag or a tag that has value outside of Javascript but little to none with Javascript - if that's not true then that particular example is a poor one.

Comment: @Theolodis Everything tagged `javascript` would automatically get the `jquery` tag. Because, you know, not enough jQuery.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot nice idea. Why not rename StackOverflow to jQueryOverflow? ;)

Comment: `selenium`+`webdriver` = `selenium-webdriver` is another candidate.

Comment: What about common mistakes when selecting tags? For example, there are a lot of posts with MySQL and sql-server? In most cases the poster is working with either MySQL or sql-server and thinks he is improving the post by adding both tags. The end result is that the first comment the poster gets is "Which database are you using MySQL or sql-server?".

Comment: @Mr.Radical See [Allow for Tag Antonyms](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265601/allow-for-tag-antonyms) on Meta SO and [Suggested tags - both sql-server and mysql are suggested by the system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207274/suggested-tags-both-sql-server-and-mysql-are-suggested-by-the-system) on Meta SE.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I wasn't aware that there was already a post for this issue.

Comment: Exclusions would make this more useful.  Often an Objective-C question is tagged with xcode.  Most (if not all) Objective-C questions are not related to xcode questions.  So, only allowing one or the other in such cases may be worth exploring.

Comment: @PortlandRunner See my comment to Mr. Radical above.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think there are too many combination of tags to automatically re-tag questions successfully.

A better auto-complete / suggested tag dialog might be better, where it takes the words in the current tags and searches for combinations of them. So in your example the user could be presented with something like this:

**Version 1:**

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

In response to comments....

**Version 2: Bolder**

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**Verison 3: Explosive**

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Here's a very ugly [tag matching query on data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/225373/retrieve-suggested-tags-based-on-4-tags) that will check for hyphenated versions of all combinations of the 4 tags provided (as 5 is the max). Obviously a real implementation of this would be far more complex to include things that aren't hyphenated and other derivatives.

Comment: You seem to be assuming people actually read this dialogue..

Comment: @JanDvorak The safest assumption is that people read nothing! :-)

Comment: This seems quite reasonable.

Comment: "Skill testing question" please sum the total tag use counts of every suggested tag and insert it into the box below.  Treat any 3s as 7s when doing so.  Use long addition, from the right top to the bottom left.

Comment: @Yakk I'm not sure I follow?

Comment: @Tanner if they are ignoring the suggestion box, create a skill testing question (add up the count of how many times the suggested tags are used) in order to post your answer.  Add in arbitrary complications if they still aren't paying attention, with the complications getting increasingly ridiculous to create a humourous effect.

Comment: In terms of implementation, the easiest way to do this is how auto-word correction works in your phone: look at tag edits, if you have a large number of tag edits from one combination to another combination, it's probably a good idea.

Comment: I agree with Jan, however, if you change the font color to red, bold it, and highlight it at least it will grab my attention.

Comment: @JonH Just for you... How's that?! Too much?! :)

Comment: Needs more flames and explosions.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Done! No more requests please!

Comment: Version 4: Blinking text

Comment: Version 5: screen goes dark, and the suggestion flashes into the user's face. There is no X button for 5 seconds. Optional eye tracker plugin for the web cam, to put the label where user is currently looking. If they somehow kill the process before 5 seconds pass, it should pop up in their BIOS next time PC starts.