# Warnings when using certain tag combinations

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-tips

<sub>Note that this is **not** the same as this question: [Tag combinations that suggest re-tagging automatically](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271397/2302862), which proposes retagging suggestions for replacing multiple tags with one, such as replacing [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap)[typeahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typeahead) with [bootstrap-typeahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-typeahead).</sub>
<sub>It is also not the same as this question: [Bootstrap tags revisited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250920/2302862) - I'm just using the bootstrap example because it's a really good one.</sub>

---

### The problem:

People misuse tags. A lot.
Have you ever seen one of those warnings?:

> [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)
> Do not use this tag for other types of DBMS (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.).

> [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone)
> DO NOT use this tag unless you are addressing Apple's iPhone and/or iPod touch specifically.

> [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap):
> Not to be confused with Twitter's Bootstrap CSS framework; please use the twitter-bootstrap tag.

> [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap):
> Use "twitter-bootstrap" and NOT "bootstrap" to ask a question about this framework.

> [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping)
> For questions about Twitter's Bootstrap CSS framework, please see the [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) tag. For "bootstrapping" in statistics, please see the [statistics-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statistics-bootstrap) tag.

> [boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boot)
> Do NOT use this tag for Spring Boot. Use [spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot) instead.

And have you seen the amount of people who don't even see them?
Just head over to the [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) tag, wait an hour or so and count how many new questions about [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) pop up over there.
Or search for [questions tagged "r" and "bootstrap"](https://stackoverflow.com/?tags=bootstrap%20r&mode=all) (I'm currently retagging most of [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap), so that list is subject to shrinking)

### An observation:

Interestingly almost all mis-tags are accompanied by a certain set of other tags. For example, *there could* be a question about [bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) (as in "running tasks on program startup") in R, however I haven't found a single question about it so far.
Or with the massive abuse of [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) in place of [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap), about 80% are accompanied by either [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress), even [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) or [twitter-bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3), or one of the countless [bootstrap-xyz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-xyz) tags.

### My feature request:

How about displaying a warning when using certain combinations of tags which are known to have a high misuse rate?
A ban would be too much, since there *can* be valid questions with almost any tag combination, but I think a little warning popup (like the one when creating a new tag) would fit pretty well.

It should also be configurable, of course.
I have something in mind like an HTML comment in the tag's description.
For example, placing this in the description of [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap):

```
<!-- bad-combination: html html5 css javascript jquery angularjs php wordpress twitter-bootstrap twitter-bootstrap-3 -->
```

would from then on present every user with a confirmation box who tries to post a question tagged [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) and one of the mentioned tags.

As always, that wouldn't prevent all misuse, but most, I think.

Comment: If someone came up with a comprehensive list of the potential problems (perhaps posted as an answer), then I'd support this feature request.  Otherwise, I think the implementation of this request is too nebulous.

Comment: Really?  No support for this request at all?  The [tag:snap-framework] tag is commonly misused by anyone wanting a "snap-into-place" behavior (usually with JavaScript or jQuery)... the tag in question is for a Haskell web framework. I retag them as I come across them, but it gets old...  [tag:foundation] is another one similar to bootstrap, [tag:zurb-foundation] should be used instead.

Comment: Related: [Stop users from tagging SSE and Server-Sent-Events in the same question, and warn for SSE + JS?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390150)  .  Also suggests alerting users that attempt to tag [javascript][sse] because they almost certainly meant [server-sent-events], not x86 SIMD.  (From 2019, no back-end support so nothing has been done about it.)

Answer (score 10):

Late answer, but I'd also totally agree with user bigblind and you. Here's another example.

---

## Yet Another Two Examples

[windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) & [dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos)/[ms-dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-dos)

[batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) & [batch-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-processing)

Note: These are the tags that usually get confused, but sometimes these combinations are correct for some questions.

---

## Observation

True enough, we are already bored and tired of mis-tags.

Sometimes they see similar tags, they think 'Whatever, just click on them.' Like SO suggests [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) together. This causes a mis-tag.

More often, users cannot tell the differences between tags. Some think [dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos) is [cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd), but these tags are not.

---

## Your request

It's actually better than my idea. My first thought was to add a bold font to

```
DO NOT USE THIS TAG WITH foo/ bar UNLESS baz
```

But a pop-up is also a good idea.

### Cons On Both Ideas

- The users can just `X` the popup. Done.
- The users can just ignore the bold text. Done.

---

## Possibly Improved System

Add the pop-up warning, and if the users dismiss them, a system should

- Have a quick review of the questions, if they seems to contains mis-tags,
- Propose those possibly mis-tagged questions into a review queue
- Humans can check if it is a mistake or not.

Perhaps a machine learning model will be good at sorting such questions.

Answer (score 4):

I'm completely in favor of this request. Here are some of the examples:

[bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap)
[babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel) (often confused with babeljs)
[sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)
[selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selector)
[iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone)

You can find more using the following query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/507530/find-often-misused-tags

Comment: Hey, late reply, but I think I found one flaw in your SE query - The string `not use` is case-sensitive. And one of the oftenly mis-used tag has the wording `NOT use` instead of `not use`.

Comment: I'm not that experienced in sequel server, and I don't have the time to look into this right now, but if you have the time and interes, I'd love it if you could edit/fork my query to correct things.

Comment: I would certainly look into that, but first let me learn how to use SE query :))

Comment: I'm sorry for my previous comment. I ended up being tempted enough to just google it, and it ended up not being too hard.

Comment: Oh. I have almost 0 knowledge on SE query and any DB things, maybe I really need some Google

Comment: I've successfully made the query case-insensitive, but how do I save the fork?

Comment: I have updated your query to a case insensitive search, here is the permalink: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/714483/find-often-misused-tags