# Can we have tag warnings or full blocks for particular tag combinations?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-wiki, tag-tips

As a very prominent example I often see questions tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) along with the [stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl) tag, that really doesn't apply validly to most of the common questions.

The STL tag wiki clearly states that it mainly refers to

> The Standard Template Library, or STL, is a C++ library of generic containers, iterators, algorithms, and function objects. Originally designed by Alexander Stepanov and Meng Lee and published by HP in 1995. Large parts of the STL were adopted with modifications into the ISO C++ Standard Library.

Also, there seems to be the [c++-standard-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-standard-library) tag that may fit better to emphasize that standard C++ algorithms and data structures are in question. Though I'm not sure as such would be needed for a question tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and not looking for the current C++ standard implementations.

I think it would be a good feature, that users should be warned about this fact, or at least fully blocked to post such combinations , when applying the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and the [stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl) tag in conjunction.

Users usually don't check tag wikis to judge their choice, as I can see from many questions.

We should have a feature, to mark specific tags/tag combinations, pop up a warning for the OP, that the selection might be wrong/misleading and explicitly ask for conformation, or we could mark particular tag combinations as invalid as all ([stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl) already implies asking for c++ anyways).

That information should be stored in the tag info records, along matching related tags, and maintained by tag editors.

The feature I'm thinking of is adding a list of conflicting tags, with a particular one, that would trigger such warning or block.

Comment: *Users usually don't check tag wikis to judge their choice, as I can see from many questions.* You are quite right, and they usually don't read warning messages either.

Comment: I would be in favor of the feature because I'm really tired of reading questions tagged [tag:node.js] [tag:requirejs] when RequireJS is not used at all in the code in the question. (People seem to think "requirejs" is a shorthand for "`require` in Node.js". I've edited the tag wiki to try to stem this but we still get mistagged questions.) However, I'm thinking Frédéric is right. The warning is unlikely to have much effect.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Then, let's simply deny such tag combinations, like we deny other commonly misused stuff?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Deny? Well, then my use-case above no longer applies because while people using [tag:node.js] [tag:requirejs] are *often* wrong, the combination is *sometimes* right.

Comment: @πάντα, and you acknowledge that in your question when you say the tag combination *doesn't apply validly to* ***most*** *of the common questions*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Sure, but I'm just tired/bored about repeating and explaining that stupid misconception a dozen times every day :-P ...

Comment: +1 from me for proposing a full block on c++ ...

Comment: @rene if we start blocking languages altogether, how quickly before php disappears? :p

Comment: @rene At least one (considerable user) backing up. Not so sure how to improve for a general proposal.

Comment: @Patrice Well, the PHP community is well known to accept crap, because the _"language "_ is crap itself. So what?

Comment: I would love to apply this idea to the "angular" and "angularjs" tag combination, given the huge number of people that apparently do not actually know the correct name of the framework they are trying to program in.

Comment: This Thread looks to me like a Duplicate of: "[Warnings when using certain tag combinations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298331/3799241)"