# What to do about Angular 2?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

As noted [here](https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/1rC5dz7AkCZP813daT_bccbS-20OLmXgBVi50CSKx148/pub) and discussed [here](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html), Google has decided to drop the "2" from [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) and refer to it simply as Angular instead, for the (very good) reason that "Angular 2" will be Angular 4 by January and Angular 6 by the end of next year.

(For those who are unfamiliar, [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) is the successor to [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) and was a complete rewrite of the platform targeting a new set of languages, so their tags are applicable to mutually exclusive sets of questions.)

So [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) is now Angular, but [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) is currently a synonym for [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs), where [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) questions expressly do not belong.

What do we do about this?

Comment: How about replacing `angularjs` with `angular1`? Most people know of AngularJS 1.4, AngularJS 1.5, etc.

Comment: I'm reminded of these They Might be Giants lyrics "Istanbul was Constantinople. Now it's Istanbul, not Constantinople. Been a long time gone, Constantinople. Now it's Turkish delight on a moonlit night."

Comment: Nonsense like this is why Google Chrome is currently at version 55, rendering version numbers effectively meaningless.

Comment: @CodyGray Ironically, this issue arose because version numbers **do** have meaning now (i.e. it's due to their shift to [semantic versioning](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html))

Comment: They have implemented semantic versioning in about the dumbest, most meaningless way possible. They concede that incrementing the major version should indicate breaking incompatible changes, but then go on to say that this will not be relevant to most software developers, and so can be ignored. Anyway, according to that article, one of their three guidelines is *"Use “Angular 1”, “Angular 2”, “Angular 4” when talking about a specific release train"*. This suggests that obliterating version-specific tags entirely may not be the correct course of action.

Comment: @CodyGray "They concede that incrementing the major version should indicate breaking incompatible changes, but then go on to say that this will not be relevant to most software developers, and so can be ignored." which is why I believe that doing any sort of [angular-version] tags is absurd.

Comment: I agree with the proposal in this question, but not in the solution that exists in the current top answer that proposes to name angular1.x tags to "angular-legacy". Calling it legacy is incorrect and misleading. Further, it is very impolite to the angular team who continues working hard to developer Angular1.x every day.

Comment: The Angular team is currently meeting with their DevRel organization to figure out how they want to brand this. Please hold off on any decisions until they have decided what they can do to help.

Comment: Is there a decision already? I'm seeing edit reviews from people removing the [tag:angularjs] from an Angular 2 question and I'm wondering if this is correct or not.

Comment: Related: [Should we remove the angularjs tag from angular2 questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315474/should-we-remove-the-angularjs-tag-from-angular2-questions)

Comment: I wonder what the process is for translating this discussion into action. Whatever else we do, it seems crystal clear that `angular` should **not** map to `angularjs`. How can that alias/synonym be removed? Who decides? Who implements? Who's in charge?

Comment: Related: tag [angular-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular-ng-if/info) (for ***ng-if***) and tag `angular-ngif` (for ***[ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)*** - two differences in spelling - one affecting the tag name)  (the former tag exists, but it seems to refer to the new version of Angular).

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I agree that all questions tagged as `angular2` should be renamed to `angular`. But I don't see any reason to rename the `angularjs` tag to `angularjs-legacy`. No one calls the framework `angularjs-legacy` and it is still under active development. Furthermore there is no sign that questions will stop being asked about `angularjs` as shown by this graph of questions asked per month

http://sotagtrends.com/?tags=[angularjs,angular]

AngularJs and Angular are the official names of two separate frameworks so I think they should have the tags `angularjs` and `angular` respectively

Comment: I agree. Those are the two names of the products, officially. I think that the tags should match.

Comment: edited my answer. Yes I think they should be left as `angularjs`. It's confusing but distinguishing between the frameworks in inherently confusing as they have almost identical names

Comment: I am on the internal Angular slack channel, and these approach, stated by @rob, is the approach that the Angular team supports. Further, it appears that the community Google Dev Experts in Angular all agree with this path as well. As an Angular GDE myself, this is definitely what I think should happen, as well as what I have heard Igor agree to.

Comment: Agree with this as well, Angular2 => Angular. AngularJS can stay AngularJS

Comment: Agreed. Sir. And as an Angular GDE I double approve this.

Comment: Personally, I see this as a poor attempt by Google to re-brand Angular after the massive change between versions 1 and 2. I guarantee you that many people are going to be very confused when asking questions. They'll begin to type in their tags and see [tag:angular] and [tag:angularjs], both of which refer to a JS framework. Newer users who are just trying to figure out how to get things working are not going to understand which one to pick. If Google wants to drop the "JS" that's fine but it's misleading to name v2 something different just because they feel like they wrote it better this time.

Comment: @MikeC fair enough. Personally I would rather the Angular team change the name of the framework to Angular 2 as that is what everyone in the community calls it. But I don't see that happening so I don't think there is a solution that won't be confusing.

Comment: @rob angular 2 version 3 :P. I prefer to not have any number and use a single tag for everything. People can state what version they are using on their questions body.

Comment: The Documentation titles for "Angular 2" needs to be renamed to "Angular" as well.

Comment: @MikeC I don't agree with you. In my opinion Angular is not a new version of AngularJS, but a new framework, with some similarities. I also think it is better to call it just angular, even if it is hard right now as it has been "angular 2" for a pretty long time.

Comment: This is now done. [tag:angular2] is now [tag:angular], and the [tag:angular] -> [tag:angularjs] synonym has been removed. There are however, a number of `[angular2-*]` tags; I'm not sure whether they (all|some) need to be mapped to `[angular]` as well?

Comment: @Matt Assuming we allow version tags for other languages, which it looks like we do, I would leave the `[angular-2.*]` tags where they are. Also, not sure if you were the one to do it but thank whoever did!

Answer (score 29):

I vote for renaming [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) to [angularjs-legacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-legacy), retagging all current [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) questions with [angularjs-legacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-legacy) and finally renaming [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) to [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular).

It'd be a lot of work but it seems like it'd be the most accurate.

Comment: I think this is inline with their guidance as well. "*Basically from now on, name all versions of Angular simply “Angular”. Try to avoid using the version number, unless it is really necessary to disambiguate.*"

Comment: Their guidance makes no sense because as long as people still using angular1, the version number is always necessary.

Comment: @BryanChen Yes, and there are many large systems written in angular1 that are defintely not going to be rewritten in angular2 anytime soon.

Comment: And who cares but the developers that still maintain them @DanM? You will have almost no new questions (aka. not-dupes) about older platforms, meanwhile newer asker can't get confused.

Comment: @Braiam:  I see a *decline* in questions about Angular 1.x, but not a sudden stop.

Comment: @Makoto numbers or didn't happen.

Comment: On other news, the [angular-1.x] tag has the amazing number of just 3 questions.

Comment: @Braiam:  I'm referring to the future.  Due to people still using Angular 1.x, I still see questions coming in.  Even with Angular 2.x advancing, there are still going to be people that don't stop with it.

Comment: @Makoto are those questions "novel"? One would expect that after 5 years of use, people would run out of new problems to ask about.... and they still have new features (!!) so, ignore me...

Comment: @Braiam "maintain" is the wrong word to use. If you're dealing with a large, complex system, and there's no time/budget/inclination/will to port the whole thing to Angular 2, that doesn't mean you're going to stop building new features.

Comment: @DanM every problem you can find with an old enough framework, was already found by someone else.

Comment: @Braiam this process is independent on whether a new version of the framework exsists or not. If new `angularjs` questions are coming in right now, they will continue to do so in the near future

Comment: @RocAràjol what are you talking about? I'm saying that old enough environment eventually run out of novel stuff to ask. What has anything to do whenever angular will continue to have new questions?

Comment: @Braiam "every problem you can find with an old enough framework" The last stable, major version release of Angular 1 was released [just this month.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#160-rainbow-tsunami-2016-12-08) I don't think that's old enough to have found all of it's quirks.

Comment: @Braiam i thought you were arguing that the `angularjs` tag would be dead since it's an old environment and thus no novel questions will appear. I'm pointing out that this is not really that relevant on a thread on Angular 1 vs Angular 2 tags.

Comment: @MikeC did you read my first reply to Makoto?

Comment: @Braiam I don't think you need numbers to know that the quirks in a major version release will not have been figured out in less than a month. As for the [tag:angular-1.x] issue, that may be due to people not knowing which tag to use. As others have said, it's likely that people are not tagging their Angular questions correctly. Hell, [people are still asking questions about .NET 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-3.5) and it was released [almost 10 years ago.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_3.5)

Comment: @Braiam Since the tag `angularjs` already exists, and refers specifically to AngularJS 1.x, I believe the onus is on you to provide numbers that AngularJS 1.x questions have "almost no new questions".

Comment: @MikeC but [nobody is answering or asking them](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/.net-3.5/topusers) only 7 question in the last 30 days, while .net managed 2k. Almost 300 times the 3.5 variant, which is my main point: what purpose serves a tag if nobody is answering said questions?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan no, my point is that I believe it would be more effective to have a single tag for the whole community that uses Angular.

Comment: @Braiam Speaking as a member of that community, I don't think that it would, since AngularJS and Angular are two very different frameworks, despite the names. People fluent in AngularJS are not going to be able to answer Angular questions. They are that different. Certainly you wouldn't suggest that C and C++ should be combined since they share the "C" part of their name?

Comment: Don't agree with this approach, Angular is the framework, and Angular.js, Angular2 etc are simply versions of it.  Therefore all the existing posts still relate to the framework.

Comment: i would suggest renaming `angularjs` to `angularjs-1.x`, this wouldn't feel like angularjs 1.x is no-longer recommended to use. (when seeing "legacy" i think about old release that are no longer recommended to use)

Comment: Calling angular1.x "legacy" is very very misleading. To start, it implies that it is dead and old, when in fact new releases of Angular 1.x come out as often as the newer Angular. Further, that isn't the name of the project. The Angular 1.x project is called "AngularJS". That is the official name from the Angular team. So I think that we should steer towards that, not the term "legacy". Calling it "legacy" has such a chronological-snobbery to it.

Comment: Official standpoint from the Angular core team is: everything version 2 and up is just angular. Angular 1 should go under the tag angularjs. It would help enormously if this was followed on SO!

Comment: Please just use the angularjs and angular tags. No need to introduce new ones. Thanks.

Comment: @SanderElias Here's the thing though: that's incredibly confusing. I can already imagine the torrent of questions coming up when newer users try to apply a solution from an [tag:angularjs] question to a [tag:angular] problem. How do we explain that? "I know that their names are almost exactly the same but trust me, they're completely different." Questions on Stack Overflow are mostly asked by newer users. People who are experienced enough to understand that they're different won't be the ones asking most of the questions.

Comment: @MikeC, As an Angular GDE I help a lot of beginners with both. I understand your fear of confusion. However, I think following the official names will clear this confusion quickly. Leaving it as is, is causing much more confusion. Adding a legacy postfix is placing a legacy label on an active framework, with is even worse.

Answer (score 12):

I agree with the comment that no one calls it Angular Legacy.

I suggest:

- Making `angularjs` an alias for `angular-1x` (same for `angular1` or `angular-1` if they exist)
- Making `Angular2` an alias for `angular`
- Doing nothing about `angular4`, etc. (leaving as separate tags)

Newer versions will come. It's useful to have version-specific tags in addition to framework specific (whether it is or not, it's a norm on Stack Overflow).

I'm hesitant even about making `angular2` an alias for `angular` in principle, but I see the benefits for this very specific version outweigh the purity.

Answer (score 11):

Now that [angular 4 is available](http://angularjs.blogspot.fr/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html), the tags [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) and [angular4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4) should be merged in [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) before it is too complicated to choose the correct tag. Otherwise in 6 months we will have the tag [angular5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular5).

Comment: Yep, it's six months later, your prediction came true. +1

Comment: Yep, [it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular5). And [for Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular6). And [for Angular 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular7). And [for Angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular8). And [for Angular 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular9). And [for Angular 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular10). And [for Angular 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular11). And [for Angular 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular12).

Comment: The [Angular 13 one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular13) is currently empty.

Answer (score 9):

I think the best way is:

- **angularjs** should be angular 1 and every version of it
- **angular** is for every version from 2 and above
- **angular2** and **angular4** (and so on) shouldn't exist at all. They should be converted to **angular** if they exist

**Angular** and **AngularJS** it's clear. There is no need to create a tag for a major version. We will have new Angular version every half if the year.

PS There is no ReactJS13 and ReactJS15 anyway.
PSS Please, don't call AngularJS *Angular-legacy*... it's a bad decision.

PS http://angularjs.blogspot.ru/2017/01/branding-guidelines-for-angular-and.html

Comment: On the other side, you have `ecmascript-5`, `ecmascript-6` and `ecmascript-7`, `java-5`, `java-6`, `java-7`, `java-8`, `java-9` and even `java-10`. These are often useful to indicate which version you are working with, in addition to the main tag.

Answer (score 2):

I think next tags could be remapped

1. [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) redirects to [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) and must be undone *(if possible)*
2. [angular1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular1.x) → [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)

   **Note:** then you got tags like [angular1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular1.6) for specific versions
3. [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) → [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)

   **Note:** then you got tags like [angular3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular3) and [angular4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4) for specific versions

Next tags shouldn't exist or must be renamed:

- [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material), [angular-ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-router), [angularjs-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-directive), [angularjs-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-service), [angularjs-ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-repeat) and [angularjs-scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-scope)→ [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)
- [angular-dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-dart) → [angularjs-dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-dart)
- [angular2-dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-dart) → [angular-dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-dart)
- [angular-ui-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-bootstrap) → [angularjs-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-bootstrap)
- [ng-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-bootstrap) → [angular-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-bootstrap)
- [angular-ui-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-grid) and [angular-ngmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ngmodel) → [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)
- And a lot more

---

**Aside note:** On documentation the tag [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) must be [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)

Comment: I **totally disagree** with deleting version related tags (such as `angularjs-1.6`). A lot of questions are **specific** to those versions, and this is why those tags exists.

Comment: @Mistalis: but it makes a lot easier. Some questions are not related to a specific version.

Comment: Making things easier is not the purpose if the site. We prefer **right** and **precise** things.

Comment: [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash/41226167#41226167) of a question 100% related to Angular 1.6. The tag is completely appropriate and deserve to exist for this one.

Comment: @Mistalis: Oke it's deleted from my answer but the tag `angular1.x` not because it makes no sense for a specific version of Angular 1.

Comment: Totally agreed. I've already made a [topic on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346079/angular1-x-is-a-synonym-of-angularjs) to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two frameworks: Angular and AngularJS.

Angular refers to Angular version 2 and every version thereafter.
AngularJS refers to version 1.

With that in mind, there should be at the very least, two distinct tags `angular` for versions 2+ and `angularjs` for all the 1.x versions.

`angular1` and `angular1.x` can be aliases for `angularjs`.

Moving forward, Angular has adopted semantic versioning but is also committed to smooth upgrades between major versions, so the distinction betweeen versions, although somewhat relevant, is still less important. As an example, the difference between Angular 2 and 4 is to add some new ngIf syntax, the use of `as` in templates and create smaller builds - nothing major from a user's standpoint.

On the other hand, there are major differences and features available between AngularJS 1.3 to 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6 so it is worthwhile to have those tags available (`angular1.3`, `angular1.4` etc).

The existing `angular2` tag should be folded into the `angular` tag. It's debatable whether you want to also adopt `angular2`, `angular4` etc as additional version clarifying tags similar to `java` vs `java-8` and `java-7` scenario. Those version tags will be useful, but not strictly necessary.

If those version clarifying tags are added though, we should still tag all existing `angular2` questions with the `angular` tag as well.

Answer (score -2):

The remaining problem after standardizing on [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) and [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) is that a number of morons (I use the term advisedly) who have not bothered to learn the correct name of the framework they are working in, and/or are too ignorant, lazy, or incompetent to read the tag descriptions, are assigning **both** tags to their questions.

Unfortunately, although the [topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306640/can-we-have-tag-warnings-or-full-blocks-for-particular-tag-combinations) has been raised on meta, currently there is apparent way to have an alert or warning presented to users assigning improbable tag combinations. There should be. In this case, the number of questions to which both tags could legitimately be assigned is probably no more than a dozen (such as questions related to migrating from AngularJS to Angular), whereas at present the number of [questions with both tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular+angularjs) is **over three thousand**.

Although normally I would agree with the decision not to use a tag such as [angularjs-legacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-legacy), since after all the framework is not named "AngularJS Legacy", in the interest of preventing people who are short more than a few neurons from mistagging their questions, it does seem reasonable to me in this case.

Answer (score -6):

There should be a consistent approach to this across the SO site.  Angular is not the first framework to undergo a transformation.  To remain consistent with the rest of the site I think you should be adding further tags to indicate the version of Angular which the question relates.  The current Angular tag should apply to all Angular questions.  This approach would seem to me to be consistent with that taken for (for example) Java, where there is a Java tag, and a Java-8 tag, or Spring, where there is a generic Spring tag, plus tags for the different specialisations of Spring (spring-boot etc).

I would suggest adding an additional tag to questions relating to the old version and making a further additional tag for questions about the newer versions

Comment: Not really comparable, the Java tag can easily be applied generically because the language and API itself expands but does not often change what already exists. Java 8 is to be used for questions about Java 8 specific features. Angular on the other hand changed drastically meaning you can't really have a generic "angular" tag to rule them all as there is little to no overlap, and they changed the naming policy to conflict with the current tags that exist to make it worse.

Comment: If I was looking for information about Angular I would expect that the Angular tag would return information about it whether, it was the old or new version.  Despite the new version being drastically different from the old version they must still belong to the Angular parent category.

Comment: @robjwilkins What would the Angular parent category consist of? If the two versions are so drastically different that they are [only similar by name](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339879/what-to-do-about-angular-2#comment423097_339882), then why not put Java and JavaScript under the same tag?

Comment: @4castle The Angular parent category should consist of EVERYTHING relating to Angular! Angular and all its offspring.

Answer (score -21):

**UPDATE:** Well, it would appear I seriously underestimated how different the two are. I'd spent a little time perusing some "what's different" pages, but now that I've heard all the comments below and done some further reading, yeah, I agree, they're pretty distinct. That said: There's still the complication that people are absolutely going to be using the term "Angular" to refer to both of these things for a while now.

=======

Sure, Angular 2 is a rewrite -- but it's still Angular. Meaning there will be lots of questions with answers that may not *directly* apply to both versions in the same way, but may apply to both with only syntactical modifications.

Think of iOS code... Objective-C and Swift are significantly different languages, however the vast majority of the iOS API is available to code written in both languages, usually with identical behavior. So you wind up with tons of iOS answers on Stack Overflow that apply to both, even though the syntax changes. Both Swift and Objective-C questions tend to have the `iOS` tag. I often find an answer to a question written in Swift and apply that to my problem in Objective-C.

So, maybe it makes sense to have an `angular-legacy` tag and an `angular2` tag, but I think the `angular` tag should be attached to both versions.

**EDIT:** I may have underappreciated how different some of the basics are. That said, there *are* still many similarities as well, at least enough that *some* tag or other ought to, I think, refer to both versions.

Comment: Angular 1.x and Angular (>= 2.x) have *very* different syntax and *very* different conventions.  You cannot expect someone who only knows Angular 1.x to be capable of answering an Angular >= 2.x question.

Comment: Yes, they are very different, but they are still a great deal more alike than, say, Angular 2.x and Express+Jade. The question, unless I'm misunderstanding here, is whether a tag should refer to both collectively, in addition to tags referring to each individually. I think NOT having a tag that encapsulates both would deprive users of answers that could be of value. Whether that tag is "angular" is another question I suppose, but for there to be NO tag that refers to both seems off to me.

Comment: You're missing my point.  Angular 1.x is similar to Angular 2.x in the same way that Java is similar to C++; they have some commonality in syntax and naming, but they've got different ways to go about things.

Comment: @Makoto I'd say that a better comparison would be accessing the same SDK (or maybe consecutive versions of an SDK) through a java API and a C# API.

Comment: As someone who's never used Angular 1.x but has spent roughly six months with Angular (2) from nothing to 1.0 release in my job, I cannot answer questions about the simplest of 1.x problems. The tags need to stay separate.

Comment: I can't find much common things between angular1 and angular2. No shared code. Not much shared concept. The language is also different.

Comment: not to bead a dead horse, but I've built a large enterprise system with Angular 1.X and having seen Angular 2 the only similarity between the two is the name and the fact they are web frameworks.