# Should version information be removed in AngularJS (2) questions?

Tags: discussion

Google [decided](https://angularjs.blogspot.de/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html) to remove the version information at AngularJS 2. In the future AngularJS 2 (or higher versions like AngularJS 4) should only be called AngularJS. We discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339879/what-to-do-about-angular-2) also about renaming tags.

Should future questions or answers be edited in order to meet the specifications of Google? So the version information in AngularJS 2 or AngularJS 4 should be removed or we want to keep them?

Comment: Should answers be edited to meet Google's whims? No, obviously not. A person answering an Angular question should know what to call it. If they choose to use a specific version number, then there is probably a reason.

Comment: The problem here is that Angular 4+ is an evolution of Angular 2 whereas Angular 1 -> 2 was a much more substantial change. [tag:angularjs] should probably remain for those older version 1 questions, but maybe we need something like `angular-io` for version 2+.

Comment: There is no such thing as AngularJS 2 (or 4). There is only AngularJS 1. Angular (no JS) started at 2 and is now at 4.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339879/1079354

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I believe so.  It's not too subjective of a call, and it's fairly straightforward when to apply the edits.

Basically, following some of the guidelines with [the requested retag effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339879/what-to-do-about-angular-2):

- AngularJS 1.x apps should just be referred to as **AngularJS**
- Angular 2+ apps should just be referred to as **Angular**
- Edits only should take place when there's enough ambiguity in the question to establish confusion
- Libraries which use the older standard of `ng2-*` should be unchanged until the libraries rename/catch up

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, and can we **please** remove the Angular synonym for Angular.js, which is not just confusing and misleading, but actively WRONG.