# Tag rename [angular2] => [angular]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Currently [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) redirects to [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)

According to Google themselves the new library is called "Angular" (no 2) as they are moving to semantic versioning and Angular v4.0.0 is coming out very soon (yes 4, not 3).

Can we follow Google and redirect all [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) to the **new** [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) and keep all old "angular1" stuff still at the [anglarjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anglarjs)?

Official link: http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html

Comment: Hmm... is this request the outcome of the discussion started by [that question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339879/what-to-do-about-angular-2)?

Comment: Haha I did not know about that one. It comes off the the official angular post here: http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html

Comment: @Floern possibly but not exactly.

Comment: This has been asked a few days ago: [Should version information be removed in angular(2) questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341132). Looks like no one really cares about doing that.