# angular1.x is a synonym of angularjs

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

[angular1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular1.x) is use on [<del>7</del> now 18 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular1.x). It is **not** a version of AngularJS, `1.x` probably means "the first version of Angular", that is [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs).

---

I think this is an exact synonym of [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs). I can't flag it as a synonym:

[image]

Note that **[15/18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular1.x+angularjs)** questions are tagged [angular1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular1.x)+[angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs).

Comment: for 7 questions shouldn't we simply retag?

Comment: @rene Of course, but the tag may be created again and again, so setting it as a tag synonym seams cleaner for me.

Comment: It can only be re-created by users with 1500 rep ... when will this angular fight be over? If that tag is not even correct blacklist it instead?

Comment: @rene I'm ok with blacklisting it. Should I update my question?

Comment: I've created it as a synonym. It'll have the same effect as blacklisting it.