# More angular tag madness: "angularjs-2.0"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I just noticed the existence of an [angularjs-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) tag with 119 questions.

This should be removed with extreme prejudice. Of course it should be [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular). How do we do that again?

(No, this is not a duplicate of [Should there be a separate 'angularjs-2.0' tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291347/should-there-be-a-separate-angularjs-2-0-tag), which is an old question about setting up a new tag for what was then the brand-spanking-new Angular 2 framework).

Comment: Maybe add it to list of synonyms of [angular](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular/synonyms)

Comment: Adding to the list of synonyms might be good, except this is actually an incorrect name--there is no such thing as angularjs-2.0. Is it considered OK to add a synonym which is an incorrect but occasionally used term for something? Anyway, when I tried to do that I was told "Version-specific synonyms can only be proposed by moderators".

Comment: There are some pre-existing arguments for and against that: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291347/should-there-be-a-separate-angularjs-2-0-tag?rq=1

Comment: @Veve No, that question is now quite obsolete.

Comment: I've removed this from all questions. Hopefully the bot will delete it now.

Comment: looks like there is [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs2)

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that with all of the confusion around angularjs vs angular that removing the tag won't be enough and that this tag should be synonymized into one of them in order to help curb any future issues. Much like [the angular-1.0 tag was merged into angularjs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346079/angular1-x-is-a-synonym-of-angularjs), this one should be merged into [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular).

Comment: It was "merged" manually by me tinto the "angular" tag. The tag in is gone.