# Is [angularjs2] a thing?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I'm asking this with respect to the [Angular 2 discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339879/559745). Now, I'm totally no expert in this domain, but my Google skills say there is no such thing, yet there are some [users](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44012244/revisions) [insisting](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43991517/revisions) it should exist. Though it's gone for the moment, the tag just keeps popping up over and over again. So I suggest to make [angularjs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs2) a synonym of [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular), unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: AngularJS is 1.x, Angular is 2+. AngularJS2 seems needlessly confusing (although, to be fair, the maintainers started it!)

Comment: [this is endless](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348232/more-angular-tag-madness-angularjs-2-0)

Comment: Alternate title: Can we look at [angularjs2] from another angle?

Comment: How about a new feature of blacklisted tags?

Comment: Perfect solution, merge all the abominations into a single tag. 0 problems afterwards.

Comment: Every 6 months this question will be asked as: "is [angularjs(n+1)] a thing now". We're already ramping up for such questions with the Angular 4 renaming.

Answer (score 17):

There are 2 frameworks:

- `AngularJS`, the first version of the framework, which is not named Angular 1 or Angular: it is **AngularJS**.
- `Angular`, the second version. It is not Angular2, or AngularJS2: it is **Angular**.

All the rest do not exist.

---

There are many tags about Angular and AngularJS that should be synonymized or burninated, but the one you linked is never used (0 question tagged), should we really do a synonym request for this?

<sub>It does not mean that I do not approve the request, but I had the feeling that the *Angular War* was about to end, and finally not.</sub>

Comment: The tag is not used at the moment because there are some users removing it on a regular basis. It keeps coming back.

Comment: I think yes so that the tag angularjs2 can never been used.

Comment: Unfortunately, the internet can't go back in time and remove all the existing content in the world that referred to AngularJs as Angular and (new) Angular as Angular2.  So count on this being a problem...forever.  Thank Google.

Comment: They really should have named angular 2 something like "rectangular" to avoid confusion.

Comment: I am *not* an Angular expert, but I have heard about "Angular" and "Angular 2" (which was in development for a long time, presumely better, and had braking changes, and now increments the version number more quickly). I would assume that Angular and AngularJS are synonyms, and would instinctively call the first one (AngularJS) "Angular", "Angular 1" or "Angular legacy", and the second one "Angular 2" (including later versions!!).... I would suggest, do the tags with the correct names that you mentioned, but add the vulgar names in the tooltips! (e.g. "[angular] - Angular 2 and later")