# Synonym [angularjs2] to [angular]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Earlier this year we had this drama: [What to do about Angular 2?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339879/what-to-do-about-angular-2) (also related [Is [angularjs2] a thing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349366/is-angularjs2-a-thing))

Today I ran across [this excerpt edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17945030) for [angularjs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs2) (rejected for lacking usage guidance). It had 140 followers(!) and one question. I promptly retagged it, per the first Meta, which removes the new tag. Can we synonym this to [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)? I guarantee someone else is going to try and recreate the tag sooner or later.

Comment: [angularjs2] has been burned