# How should separate Angular 2 and angular documentation tags be handled?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Currently in the [Documentation section](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) there is a tag for [Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/topics) and [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular/topics) separately. Is there a way to request a merge of these to prevent duplicated effort?

I think that "angular" would be the correct one because the tag is [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) and also from what is discussed in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339879/what-to-do-about-angular-2)

Comment: You have to get a developer or community team member to merge tag Documentation. Hopefully one will see this question and be inspired. Moderators don't have the privilege, nor do gold tag badge holders. The best that can be done otherwise is an excessively laborious manual merge of the individual topics, then deleting them. Even if that is done, you'd still be left with an orphaned tag that will sit there inviting people to re-add the same content back to it.

Comment: @CodyGray would it worth sending an email, or is this likely to be seen?

Comment: No point in sending an email. You could raise a custom "in need of moderator intervention" flag and describe the merge you want to see happen. (As far as I know, these moderator flags don't go to normal moderators, but the community team members you want to see them.) But they do monitor the Meta site, too. Don't expect anything to happen in a hurry. I've submitted a number of these requests, and so far, Shog9 is the only one I've seen ever handle them, and he's a pretty busy guy. The support provided by the team for Documentation is *extremely* sub-par.