# The tag "angular4.x" can't be browsed

Tags: support, tags

I discovered that there is a tag called [angular4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4.x) but when I try to search for [angular4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4.x) I get redirected to the [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) tag. Is this a bug and if not why [angular4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4.x) is not browsable?

Comment: thats because it is [set as a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular/synonyms). Not a bug. `angular2`,`angular4.x` are essentially the same as the parent tag `angular`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check this [meta stackexchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work) regarding tag synonyms, and [this subsequent decision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339879/1079354) regarding Angular and its versioning with tags going forward.

[angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) currently has a number of similar tags set as synonyms which includes [angular4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4.x). Check the synonyms [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular/synonyms).

- [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2)
- [angular4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4)
- [angular4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4.x)

Any questions tagged with the synonyms get automatically set to `angular` tag. Also searching for synonym tag gets you the parent tag.
This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)