# Rename [angular2-*] to [angular-*]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Since new version of AngularJS framework is officially referred to as only **Angular**, I think all of the existing `angular2-*` tags should be renamed or merged to existing `angular-*` tags, here's the list:

- [angular2-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-routing) => [angular-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-routing)
- [angular2-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-template) => [angular-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-template)
- [angular2-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-forms) => [angular-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-form)
- [angular2-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-services) => [angular-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-service)
- [angular2-directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-directives) => [angular-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-directive)
- [angular2-nativescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-nativescript) => [angular-nativescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-nativescript)
- [angular2-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-components) => [angular-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-component)
- [angular2-observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-observables) => [angular-observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-observable)
- [angular2-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-http) => [angular-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-http)
- [angular2-aot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-aot) => [angular-aot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-aot)
- [angular2-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-testing) => [angular-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-testing)
- [angular2-changedetection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-changedetection) => [angular-changedetection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-changedetection)
- [angular2-formbuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-formbuilder) => [angular-formbuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-formbuilder)
- [angular2-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-material) => [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material)
- [angular2-pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-pipe) => [angular-pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-pipe)
- [angular2-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-modules) => [angular-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-module)
- [angular2-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-cli) => [angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-cli)
- [angular2-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-router) => [angular-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-router)
- [angular2-animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-animation) => [angular-animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-animation)
- [angular2-guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-guards) => [angular-guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-guard)
- [angular2-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-injection) => [angular-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-injection)

If I missed any, please let me know and I'll add them. You'll also notice that I changed some words from plural to singular. Since this is my first time writing on `meta`, sorry if my terminology is not on point, I don't visit `meta` very often.

Comment: Related: [What to do about Angular 2?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339879/2675154)

Comment: Yes, and get rid of tags like `angularjs-http` and have just `angular-http` suitable for all versions and hope people correctly have the other tag `angular` or `angularjs` on their question (as there are 3,116 questions with both of those tags on...)

Comment: @George I'm not sure about that, that needs to be carefully thought. Might be an overkill in my opinion. But something definitely needs to be done about those tags, that's why I started this discussion.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota at the moment (according to the description) `angular-http` should only be for angularjs and yet it's pretty much used for all versions

Comment: one thing to mention is v5 compared to v2/v4. v5 now uses HttpClient as the main http module and deprecates Http

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The stable versions pretty strictly follow semver. Tag versioning issues then should be handled the same as any other library.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota Could you use [tag styles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tags) in your post so it's easy to view the tag info?

Comment: This angular mess is going to get out of control. It's going to get out of control and we'll be lucky to live through it.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The same way it works for other systems. You should use a main tag with a version e.g. `angular-5.x` and then specify the component you are using without a version. There is no reason to have things like `angular2-injection`, `angular4-injection` and `angular5-injection` (I would actually argue that the tag is superfluous completely since it’s a core part of Angular anyway).

Comment: @Will Honestly, this mess is caused by how tags are designed on Stack Overflow, namely that we have unique tags (eg. [tag:angular-testing]) rather than "re-using" tags (eg. [tag:angular] + [tag:testing]). If we didn't do that, we only had to rename the main tag and we would be done. I'm not saying that that system would be better, but it's something we have to deal with due to it.  But I really wonder if all these tags are necessary, do we need an [tag:angular2-formbuilder] tag?

Comment: If I remember well, most of angularjs-* have been burninated. angular-* tags should be the same. Unless they're 3rd party components and not provided by the framework. No one is gonna follow one of those specific tags (or all that existed when they checked). It is fair enough to know that we're dealing with angular.