# Angular tag confusion and discussion?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

[angular5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular5) tag should be merged with [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) tag. [angular5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular5) tag is having approx 3k question associated with it.

Comment: It is quite a common pattern to have an overall product tag and version specific tags.

Comment: i think Than for every angular 2 , angular 4 we should have tag ? if we want to go version specific @Gimby

Comment: You don't really just create tags, they get created as soon as questions need them.

Comment: yes Thats why i am saying to merge angular5 tag to angular as there is only two version of angular . angularjs and angular

Comment: Anyone with [1500](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) rep can create a tag if their question needs it.

Comment: @Gimby I wrote the same thing on above comment. for angular there should be only two tags angularjs and angular (2 And above) not version specific

Comment: @SurajRao thats why Saying To merge the tag !

Comment: (*previous comment makes no sense, deleted it*). Just because Angular 5 exists now does not mean Angular 2 or 4 never existed. The reason why we have version tags is so questions can be linked to specific versions and you can identify when a question and its answers may be potentially out of date for your purposes if you are using a far newer version.

Comment: angular in general has a [big mess with its tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bburninate-request%5D+angular), if we stop the burn every useless tag that we can find maybe we could dig into this instead.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360093/rename-angular2-to-angular . Angular 2 was renamed to angular in this thread so all version should be merged into single version to get best possible outcome

Comment: v5 has its own [specific features](https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced). Even [angular5 info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular5/info) says _Use this tag for Angular questions which are specific to only version 5. Use tag Angular for any Angular questions which are not specific to an individual version._ I find myself agreeing with [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346164/4826457)

Comment: I agree with Suraj and people should also consider that tags are used by search engines, when I have been searching google for angular4 topics SO gives me tons of answer in angular-js, probably some deeper thoughts how to organize all this is needed when we have finished messing around with [multiple], [height] and other useless tags.

Comment: @SurajRao but if we have version specific tag than it can become confusing with angular-6 ,7,8,9 .So if we want to maintain the tag than angular 2 and angular 4 tag should be made as swift 2 swift3 swift 4 tags are there

Comment: The overall idea is that you use a version-specific tag if the question is version-specific. But if it is just a generic Angular question, you use the Angular tag. The truth is probably more that a whole bunch of questions need to be retagged rather than a tag merge needing to happen.

Comment: @Amey leave this question, the angular problem is one of the big tag problems of SO, if someone manages to come up with a good strategy of tagging these questions, that consider both OP asking question, people answering and people searching for solution. I'm ready to spend significant amount of time to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

I know `angular2` and `angular4` are synonyms for `angular`, but versions of angular will keep coming ([Angular 6](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4) now exists with `angular6` tag) and we do not know what differences they will contain.

In general we could:

1. convert every new release to synonym of `angular`, ignoring what differences exists between versions.
2. [burninate version tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346072/now-can-we-burninate-the-angular4-tag) for every new release, ignoring what differences exists between versions.
3. **Do nothing**.

I think we should follow option 3 and do nothing because:

- It requires least amount of work
- You can subscribe to specific version of tag if you are working with it.
- Tags make discovery and categorization easier than writing version in question.

So let `angular5` and any `angularX` be as a version tag.