# Webdriver.IO tags cleanup

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

[Webdriver.IOs](https://webdriver.io/docs/gettingstarted/) current version is **7**, and for some reason each version has its own tag.

I suggest to map all of them to a new tag, `wdio`.

Current tags:

- [`wdio-v5`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wdio-v5/info) 49 questions
- [`wdio-v6`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wdio-v6/info) 27 questions
- [`wdio-v4`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wdio-v4/info) 23 questions
- [`wdio-jasmine`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wdio-jasmine/info)
- [`webdriver-io`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/webdriver-io) 1300 questions

**Update:**
Why `WDIO` and not `Webdriver.IO`: `WDIO` is the best practise naming for this testing framework, here are some references:

- the cli is called [wdio](https://webdriver.io/docs/clioptions/)
- all npm packages are in the namespace [@wdio](http://npmjs.com/search?q=%40wdio)
- the documentation contains 257 times wdio[image]

I believe everyone asking question to this is looking for `wdio` in the first place and not `Webdriver.IO`.

Alternative would be to create a `wdio-v7` tag or a `Webdriver.IO`...

Is there some elegant way to get this done?

Comment: `wdio` seems to be an (unnecessary) obfuscation. Why not `webdriverio`?

Comment: thats their own creation, ```wdio``` is used in their entire documentation. It is also the npm namespace: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=%40wdio

Comment: There is a difference between an [npm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)) package name and the actual name.

Comment: You need to back up your statements with evidence. ["WebdriverIO" is](https://webdriver.io/docs/setuptypes) [used throughout](https://webdriver.io/docs/gettingstarted) [in the](https://webdriver.io/docs/options) [documentation](https://webdriver.io/docs/typescript).

Comment: Related: *[What should we do about Angular 2?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339879/what-to-do-about-angular-2/345913#345913)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen we already have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdriver-io so I guess the best way forward is making those wdio-{version} tags synonyms of that [tag:webdriver-io] tag.

Comment: is there a difference between tagging a question with [tag:wdio-jasmine] or [tag:webdriver-io] and [tag:jasmine]?

Comment: @rene oh, i didn't see the ```webdriver-io``` tag. Their documentation has mostly a "." between webdriver and IO. Sounds reasonable.