# Blacklist [batch]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process, blocklist-request

Being active in the [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) area, it often happens that questions tagged with something like "[spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring) [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file)" appears and actually refers to [spring-batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-batch). I assume that the users tagged the question with [batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch) which is then moved to [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) automatically.
Now I wondered whether it would make sense to let the tag drop completely (can be used for different things ([batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) [batch-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-processing) [spring-batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-batch))) or generally let it point to [batch-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-processing) (which now that I think about it is not a good idea...).

Why I think the tag should be blacklisted:
Tagging a question with [batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch) is not always going to produce the tag intentionally wanted. There are many ways batch can be laid out (be it as in batch operations in a database, batch-files, spring-batch or batch-processing or batches in machine learning, etc.).
In the [tag-wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonym-request/info) of synonym-request here on Meta it reads:

> Please also, when posting suggestions, try to avoid creating tag collisions; see [this example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75332).

That example shows a similar case to this one where a synonym ended up with more than one meaning. The proposed solution was to make minor changes to the synonym so that each one gets its own meaning. Similar to this already tags exist for [batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch) so blacklisting could solve the issue.
Additionally [@ErikVonAsmuth](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-von-asmuth) stated [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356684/blacklist-batch?noredirect=1#comment515073_356684) that batch should be blacklisted and not removed as it still could be recreated with the same issues as before by users not being aware of the problem that see the tag as a good way of typing less for "their" main tool.

I am unsure if there is something I am missing to make this a good meta question; it is my first one in tag discussions.

Comment: That is why I made this a discussion first. There are many members in this comunity that are more experienced in how to handle such things. I just wanted to mention this "issue" at first and look how the responses are :)

Comment: Note that what makes blacklisting the tag a good idea, in my opinion, is that people are apparently using [tag:batch] a lot without having a second look at which tag that actually produces. If we don't blacklist the tag but remove the synonym, these people will get a prompt to create it, and we will have an ambiguous tag on our hands. Blacklisting will avoid this issue (we generally want to avoid blacklisting whenever possible, but this is a good candidate for it in my opinion).

Comment: Did you consider a tag warning: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips

Comment: I did not so far because I was unaware of them existing. And here comes the reason back again why I initially made this a discussion. I am unsure if I am able to actually answer the questions. Anyways. I am unsure how much that would do. SQL is a tag on its own and not a synonym. The warning asks for more context and information which is not 100% required. If you click [Post] with the batch tag still in there the question will be tagged differently no matter what which is not the case for sql

Comment: @rene Do you know if you can make those work for synonyms, but not for the main tag? I didn't suggest it because I thought they didn't.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth ah, that is a good observation where I can only assume it works like all the other warnings and that is with a regex in which case it woudn't matter whether it is a synonym or not.

Comment: *Strongly* related, probably a duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355221/how-to-rectify-use-of-batch-file-tag

Comment: @CodyGray Yes indeed. I must have missed that one. I will drop a little text over there then. But I would like to leave this one still as the other one does not include any change tags and it does not look like a dev has taken action (or even notice?) if that is ok (despite it getting 2 downvotes already for reasons I cannot really follow). I understand the dupe one, but there has been one before.