# Stop users from tagging SSE and Server-Sent-Events in the same question, and warn for SSE + JS?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-disambiguation

**TL:DR**: make it impossible for the initial tags on a question to include both
`[sse]` and `( [server-sent-events] or [php] or [javascript] )`

Or at least prompt for confirmation like "Did you mean [server-sent-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-sent-events) instead of [sse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sse) (x86 SIMD) in a [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) question?"

Perhaps also pop up the tag-usage guidelines for both tags for cases where one is an abbreviation for the other.

---

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info is x86 SIMD with 128-bit vectors, usually for C/C++ intrinsics or assembly-language questions about manual vectorization, or how to get compilers to auto-vectorize.  (I have a gold badge in this and some related tags.)

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/server-sent-events/info is the HTTP/HTML5 thing.  It's usually abbreviated SSE, but of course that tag name was already taken.  (I never look at this tag except mistagged questions).

There is zero connection between these things, and I've never seen a mistagged question about Server Sent Events that was even in a language that gives any control of SIMD.  (Usually JS and/or a server-side language like PHP).

It's understandable that some people in a hurry will mistag their `[server-sent-events]` question as `[sse]`.  We x86/sse/simd tag followers regularly edit a few questions a week to fix that.  It doesn't bother me, reading every tag-usage popup is a lot to ask especially for a user's first question.

**The frustrating thing is when people tag *both***.  They've obviously *found* both tags but read neither of them, despite the surprising condition of apparently "2 tags for the same thing".  (That does happen on SO, but that's a terrible good assumption to make without checking.)  It seems obvious to me that one should read both tag popups to find out what's going on, but some people apparently don't respect Stack Overflow enough to avoid wasting my time.

There seem to be more such questions recently than I remember seeing, like 2 such questions in the last 2 days, annoying me enough to suggest this.  Or maybe just those combined with regular mistagged `[sse]` questions (that didn't use both).

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58256742/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58246623/revisions
- idk how to search for questions that were initially tagged both, or that are now tagged `[server-side-events]` and were edited by me or some of the other SSE/x86 tag regulars.

---

I'm having a hard time imagining a question about using SIMD to optimize the server or client side of server-sent-events that wasn't way too broad for SIMD (usually that's about one loop over one or a couple arrays).  There are [a handful of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bserver-sent-events%5D%20%28%20%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%20or%20%5Bc%5D%20%29) tagged [server-sent-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-sent-events) and ( [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) or [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) ) but unsurprisingly they have nothing to do with SIMD.

**Therefore I don't see a problem with making it impossible to tag both (if that's doable), or at least making users confirm it.**

Maybe also warn / require confirmation for `[sse] ( [javascript] or [php] )` ; I searched and there was [one such question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27789114/use-javascript-to-fetch-a-variable-from-a-separate-php-file) but it was actually about server sent events and had merely slipped through the cracks until now (so I fixed it).

Note that Python + NumPy and libraries like TensorFlow do have lots of valid `[sse]` questions, so not all "server side" languages can get this treatment.  Some JS JIT engines may use SSE internally or even expose the ability to do manual vectorization.  [SIMD.js was a failed attempt at that](https://01.org/node/1495), but hopefully(?) future work will replace it.  So a confirmation like "are you sure you meant SSE (x86 SIMD) instead of [server-sent-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-sent-events) in a JavaScript question?" is the most we should do, not a ban on combining those tags.

But we can safely ban `[sse] + [php]` and `[sse] + [server-sent-events]`, especially for initial posts.  Edits can still fix it if the rare case ever comes up, if we want to be super cautious.

---

A 'did-you-mean feature' for JS and PHP will probably catch a lot of questions that were only going to use `[sse]` and hadn't found the `[server-side-events]` tag at all.  So that's probably really good.

Comment: I'm not if there is an infrastructure for this but it will be good if we have it. A lot of people tag with both `[java]` and `[javascript]` when they actually mean one or the other. Each of the tags starts with "Not to be confused with <the other tag>" but, alas, some users just don't read. There are other ones, too - I saw `[depth-first-search]` and `[dfs]` once - the latter is actually a file system, according to the tag, not an algorithm.

Comment: @VLAZ: When I started writing this, I was only thinking of excluding a specific impossible tag-pair to fix the one case I was annoyed about.  But probably the more useful feature is *warning* about highly-unlikely tag combos that normally only occur as mistakes.  That can be used more widely without creating a roadblock like a true ban would.  Like your `[java] [javascript]`, which is possible.  e.g. maybe a question from someone that knows one language asking how to do something similar in the other.  Would help to reduce frustration by regulars from people wasting their time.

Comment: Perhaps `sse` should be expanded too, to `streaming-simd-extensions` :P

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: lol, please no.  (For the benefit of readers not familiar with SSE, that formal name is *very* rarely used. Although surprisingly, a google for `site:stackoverflow.com streaming simd extensions` got about 1000 hits, including a quote from Intel's optimization manual.  So it does get used outside of just the format definition, but mostly only in Intel manuals or by beginners who don't know that *everyone* abbreviates it).  *If* we did need to rename `[sse]`, I'd suggest `[sse-simd]`.  But unless we blacklisted `[sse]`, it would soon get recreated by one usage or the other.

Comment: I would prefer that this FR was about blacklisting sse, which is easier rather than creating a exclusion system.

Comment: @Braiam: how would that be useful?  It's a tag with 1870 questions, many of them good and on-topic.  SSE is the only name most people use for the technology.  Do you want to ban acronyms from tags in general?  If my choices were occasionally fixing the tags in questions or having to look at `[streaming-simd-extensions]` bloating the tag list in every question, I'd choose the status quo.  Although it would set it apart from tags like `[sse2]` and `[sse4]` that are about specific versions of SSE, while the `[sse]` tag is more of a catch-all than SSE1 specifically.  (But SSE1 is just called SSE)

Comment: Because the objective is that people stop using an ambiguous tag (since it has two meanings). The easiest way, which doesn't require SE to sink resources creating another tooling is blacklisting.

Comment: @Braiam: There are several other tags that are ambiguous, e.g. `[mars-simulator]` is the MIPS simulator of that name, while `[mars]` is something else.  I think new tooling is better than making our tag names less nice, harder to find, and slower to type (in searches).  If someone's looking for the tag for SSE, they're going to try `sse` first, not `streaming-simd-extensions` or `x86-sse`.  Although `sse-simd` is at least discoverable, it risks visual confusion of whether a question is already tagged `simd` or not, as well as `sse`.

Comment: Lets go ala Jack the Ripper, piece by piece. You brought this tag to attention, lets deal with it before going for others.

Comment: @Braiam: What do you propose renaming `[sse]` to?  I don't much like any of the possibilities I've thought of.  If you want to post a new meta question about your proposed solution, that's fine.  I'll link to it from this question.  But I'd rather keep this question be about automatically catching unlikely tag pairs.

Comment: To nothing. As you already noted, sse can refer to several things. Just remove the TLA from the system to prevent confusion.

Comment: @Braiam: SSE needs a tag; it's the most important / specific tag in many questions.  Renaming is possible, but simply removing it would be a horrible idea.  Your suggestion makes zero sense.  Also, the existing tag wiki is pretty good; throwing it away and posting a fresh copy of the latest revision in some newly-created tag also makes no sense.

Comment: @Braiam The streaming SIMD extensions (an x86 instruction set extension) are basically only known under the SSE term.  Getting rid of that tag would make it practically impossible for users to find the right tag here.

Comment: @fuz Didn't you just come with a better tag name? [streaming-simd-extensions]?

Comment: @Braiam Most programmers don't actually know that this is what SSE stands for and will not be able to find the correct tag like this.

Comment: @fuz then time for them to learn.

Comment: @Braiam That's not how this works.  You can't demand that user remember obscure acronyms like this.  They'll just end up not applying a tag at all.

Comment: @fuz I prefer them not applying a ambiguous tag. If that what it takes, so be it.

Comment: @Braiam: You don't get to decide that everyone needs to use an unusual clunky name they wouldn't think of typing just because you've decided that would be better than the common well-known name.  It would be possible to have a tag like [x86-simd] as a catch-all for SSE/AVX/AVX-512, or maybe [sse-x86] if you want to disambiguate it from things that abbreviate to SSE.  But I think those would be worse choices than keeping the existing [sse] name.  (But x86-simd won't show up as a completion when someone types "sse", and isn't specific to SSE without AVX)

Comment: @Braiam: To be fair, I don't mind that you originally suggested an idea; that's fine.  But continuing to argue for it after experienced SO users in that tag tell you it has showstopper problems is not helpful.  No thank you, we don't want to do that.  Sometimes the real world is messy and doesn't fit your notions of what you think would be ideal, so tradeoffs need to be considered when there isn't an ideal solution that suits everybody without causing any long-term pain for anyone.

Comment: Well, then be happy having the same problem that you have now and don't complain when you don't get the result you expect. I've seen this several times with other tags, every time it happens as I said. I'm just frustrated that people seems to just blindly walking towards the same pit over and over again.

Comment: @Braiam: Yes there is a problem, and proposing a good solution to it was the point of this meta question.  Without that feature, though, any other solution has to avoid causing other even worse problems, whether via tag-renaming or something else.  For example, `[sse-x86]` or `[sse-simd]` would be worth considering as possible names.  They seem ugly, but we could certainly live with those, unlike `[streaming-simd-extensions]`.

Comment: The only problem I see is those languages which can be used for both streaming SIMD extensions and server side events. I'm assuming that one could write a program using C++ that would be capable of issuing server side events. You could also write a program using C++ that would take advantage of SSE in processors. So who would maintain the list of "clashing tags"? Gold badge holders? I am doubtful that someone would hold a gold badge in both [server-side-events] and [sse], but it could happen. I know! A queue! :P.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: The point of this idea is to *reduce* the amount of mis-tagging, not prevent it entirely, so clashes in uncommon corner cases can be ignored.  (There might be some [server-sent-events] [c++] questions, but I've never seen one mis-tagged [c++][sse]).

Comment: Well, your proposal mentions making it **impossible** to add both, so... I like the idea of a warning, but saying "it'll never happen" seems like an invitation to hold someone's beer. I also like the idea of warning on first post, then warning again on every self-edit if they ignore the first time.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Note that I never proposed blocking [c++][server-sent-events], because that tag name is self explanatory and clear enough not to need assistance to use it correctly.  The relevant example would be [javascript][sse], if calling out to native code from node.js.  (I have actually worked on a project that did exactly that, but the JS is insulated from the C++ via node.js's standard call-a-C-function stuff so the only question that comes to mind is writing JS to use SIMD-friendly data layouts.)  I guess there's also [webassembly].

Comment: @HereticMonkey: But yes, agreed, "impossible" could well create problems, hence backing off from that in the next paragraph.