# Should [assemblies] be a synonym of [.net-assembly]?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

These two tags have similar numbers of questions (3k for [.net-assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-assembly) vs. 2.3k for [assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assemblies)).  I don't know which is used most in recent months / years, but `.net-assembly` has the more explicit name.

I don't know enough about .net to know if there's *any* meaningful difference between them.  If not, probably we should keep `.net-assembly` and make `assemblies` a synonym of it. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/.net-assembly/synonyms

Tag descriptions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/.net-assembly/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/assemblies/info

---

PS: I only know about these tags from fixing the tags on questions mis-tagged `[assembly]` (assembly language), so I don't have the rep to even suggest this tag synonym myself.  I always pick `[.net-assembly]`, often just by inserting a `-` instead of space between `.net` and `assembly`.  /sigh.  That's been a problem forever, and feature requests for incompatible-tag filters / sanity-check confirmations have been ignored, both [long ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202961/how-to-address-c-net-users-mis-use-of-the-assembly-tag#comment646012_202961) and [recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390150/stop-users-from-tagging-sse-and-sever-sent-events-in-the-same-question-and-warn).  But that's not what this question's about, merely why I'm posting about a tag I'm not active in.

Comment: It seems that sometimes the [assemblies] tag is used in not .net context, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59514878/why-does-debugger-crash-for-movebx-ax). It seems a misuse of this tag effectively, but simply merging the tags could increase confusion.

Comment: @Damien: Thanks, but that example is very clearly (to me) just a mis-tagged [tag:assembly] question about x86 asm, so I fixed its tags.  I'd be more worried about questions like [tag:maven-assembly-plugin] or whatever other Java tool "assembles" a bunch of stuff into a single file.  We occasionally get questions about that mis-tagged as `[assembly]` and I'm sometimes less sure what to do about them because no keywords in the text jump out as matching any tag.

Comment: I agree, but how to handle these misuses if tags are merged?

Comment: @Damien: Creating tag synonyms doesn't retag existing questions, only when new questions are posted or existing questions are edited.  It's not a true merge.  Having [assemblies] auto-complete to [.net-assembly] will hopefully reduce the incidence of typos in future question; someone's hopefully more likely to notice that .net-assembly isn't the name they want when picking from possible auto-completions for `assem...`, so that's a good point in favour of making this synonym.

Comment: @Damien: And for existing mis-tagged old questions, I don't see how that would make it worse even if it did re-tag them.  If anyone ever notices the mis-tagging, they can fix it.

Comment: I understand. I misunderstood the consequences of this "make synonym" action. Misuses will become more clear with your proposal.

Comment: Isn't this the equivalent of just removing [tag:assemblies]?

Comment: @Braiam: Maybe that would be a better idea because it's somewhat ambiguous with things that aren't .net.  That would involve retagging old existing questions, right? (We don't want to leave old questions without either tag.)  Making a synonym has a lower threshold of checking that it's the right thing to do first.