# Add hint / warning for specific tag combinations?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, new-users, tag-tips

I see a lot of questions in the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) realm, where the tag is applied unconsciously, primarily by new contributors.

Especially some combinations like [arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino) (should be [arduino-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino-c%2b%2b), or [net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/net)/[cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cli) (should be [c++-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli)) lead to very specific dialects, which may be very distinct from the standard language.

Would it be a good idea to install (community driven) warnings for the OP during tag application, that the combination might not be appropriate for the one or the other tag?

(I am a bit tired of editing and replacing those tags all the time.)

Comment: Related similar topic: [Can we get a warning when a user tags multiple DBMSs?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286965/can-we-get-a-warning-when-a-user-tags-multiple-dbmss) Though it's not just new users; I see users with 1,000's of reputation tag incorrectly. The real problem is that they *don't care*; a warning likely isn't going to stop them considering that many users don't bother to read the [tour], the messages in the wizard, or even learn from comments telling them to *tag properly* in prior questions. (This isn't to say I'm against the idea, I would *love* better tagging.)

Comment: We know,  most users _don't read_, or even _care_.

Comment: As far as I know, it's common practice to tag specific dialects and versions of a language with the main language tag, even if they deviate substantially (e.g. SQL, the tag is appropriate even when using a DBMS which is miles away from any ANSI SQL standard). There's even been the whole [x-vba discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370095/7296893), and following the same logic arduino-c++ may be a poor tag. I'm not sure if removing the c++ tag in these cases is a good edit and if the tag shouldn't be used.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Warnings when using certain tag combinations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298331/1478931) – also possibly related: [Tag combinations that suggest re-tagging automatically](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271397/1478931)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warnings when using certain tag combinations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298331/warnings-when-using-certain-tag-combinations)

Comment: @V2Blast: Also related: [Stop users from tagging SSE and Server-Sent-Events in the same question, and warn for SSE + JS?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390150)  .  Also suggests alerting users that attempt to tag [javascript][sse] because they almost certainly meant [server-sent-events], not x86 SIMD.  (From 2019, no back-end support so nothing has been done about it.)

Comment: This is maybe also useful for the combination of the python and python-3.x tags.

Comment: @The_spider python-y.x *explicitly* needs [tag:python], as it says in the tag-excerpt of each of those. The problem is usually people adding only a specific version, or adding the version tag when the question is actually generic.

Comment: @V2Blast The related/duplicate issue is 7 years old with no new activity. It is IMHO forgotten. Closing this issue is to leading the OP into the dead-end.

Comment: I just want to emphasize **very specific dialects, which maybe very distinct from the standard language**. The other examples given, regarding language versions should still have the standard language tag.

Comment: It would be nice if staff members who provide potential dupes for requests also give an update on those duplicates as to the status of said request, at the very least.

Comment: @Adriaan That's what I mean. I see a lot of people adding both python and python-3.x to their question, while their question is just a general python question. A warning asking whether the question is specific about python 3 would be useful for users doing that.

Comment: @The_spider I definitely meant  to address a different problem, as emphasized in my comment.

Comment: I was only saying that a warning could also be usefull in solving different problems.

Comment: This kind of engine would also help with the troves of folks referring to "CMD.exe" as "DOS" or "Batch-File" as "DOS" and hopefully alleviate my eyeballs from the troves of `wishing to be helpful` individuals making a big deal about the differences just to be pedantic. . .