# Alert user when combining certain tags on a question

Tags: feature-request, tags

Is it possible to make certain tags on questions mutually exclusive?  Or perhaps some kind of notification when users try to mix certain tags?

For example: I look over SQL related questions on a regular basis and it never fails that you'll find questions tagged as `MYSQL` and `SQL-Server`.  No doubt many of you have seen the same as I can almost always find a comment asking the OP which it is.  No doubt there are other tags like this, but these are the examples that I see most often.

I realize that it says explicitly on the tag not to combine these and exactly which RDBMS these tags refer to.  It seems obvious to me that the descriptions on these tags (and other related help information) are either not being read or outright ignored.

I think adding this feature would reduce confusion from our users asking questions in addition to reducing work from potential question answerers by endlessly asking for basic clarification which could've been included at the start.

I didn't find the below previous discussion prior to asking this question, so this may well be closed as a duplicate.

[Allow for Tag Antonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265601/allow-for-tag-antonyms?rq=1)

Comment: I don't think they should be mutually exclusive as occasionally questions are relevant to both but certainly a warning as 99% of the time they only want one. (Usually the MySql one is the one that is incorrectly added in my experience). There is already a reminder mechanism to tag a RDBMS. This could be made smarter.

Comment: @MartinSmith I agree, I can see situations where you'd be asking a question that refers to both / multiple.  I softened my language in the request.

Comment: Should tags [tag:windows] and [tag:linux] be considered mutually exclusive then?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ probably not. Unless that is a commonly mis tagged combination?

Comment: @MartinSmith I just wanted to point out such bad concept.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The concept is to attempt to prevent consistent user input errors with a simple notification.  What part of that do you disagree with?

Comment: And what if I am trying to connect to both MySQL and SQL Server? Out of luck?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this is a very common issue in the SQL tags with an obvious solution.  [the vast majority of these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server+mysql) are tagged incorrectly. Probably many more were later tagged correctly after a round of clarifications that wasted the time of all involved.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you'd click through on the notification in the softened version.

Comment: This is a nice idea. I also see this happen a lot for [asp.net] combined with [mvc] or [model-view-controller], where the user could be alerted that they probably want [asp.net-mvc]. This will also prevent the many trivial edits that are currently being done on those posts, which fix none of the other issues with the posts other than retagging.

Comment: Agree this could have a look. Currently [over 6,000 posts tagged with both](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bsql-server%5d%20%5bmysql%5d%20is%3aquestion&searchOn=3), and I bet over 5,000 of those are incorrect.