# Has Stack Overflow become too big?

Tags: discussion, split-stack-overflow

For a lot of discussions on Meta of late, about quality of answers, speed of answering, huge number of duplicates and more, the problem to me seems to boil down to the huge amount of traffic (questions, answers, comments).

So I wondered, has Stack Overflow become too large? Should it be broken down into a bigger number of more specific programming sites in the Stack Exchange network? There are already specific sites for professional programmers, DBadmins, system administrators. Would a solution like that be viable for the non-professional or not-necessarily-professional Stack Overflow as well?

I think that because SE sites like Programming, DBA, Server Fault, Game Development are more specialized, that they will attract more experienced users who are interested in the specific subject, leading to more and better answers. My reasoning is that the omnipresent and comprehensive scope of SO actually cannibalizes those other SE sites. SO made sense when it was smaller, but now I think SE sites (both new and existing) dedicated to a more specific subject are better, because they have more focus and less noise. The only thing in their way is Stack Overflow itself, because there is a place for just about any question.

In a way, I'm trying to say: "Stack Overflow must die!" but then making it sound a bit less evil, because the mere suggestion makes everybody go "woop woop woop woop!". ;-)

Comment: You could try to launch a new site proposal on Area51...

Comment: This *has* been discussed before; because programmers are learning **all the time** you cannot segregate the community into learners and pros.

Comment: The community is big, and of course every community has some problems. But due to the number of users most of the time you get an answer almost instantly. That is just great.

Comment: @MartijnPieters To clarify: I don't mean to segregate by education level per se, but rather separate by subject. Maybe have a dotNETExchange and a WebdevExchange.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's still a strawman argument. _Everybody_ is learning all the time; but there's a huge difference between a professional programmer learning the syntax and semantics of a new programming language or the intricacies of a new library, and the many thousands of people who come here to ask quesions like "I can has NullPointerException?" who don't have any clue. There's other, better arguments against such a segregation, for example that it simply would be too much work to keep the quality high (see the SO front page...), so please don't reiterate the bad arguments.

Comment: @GolezTrol, so where should I post my ASP.NET questions?

Comment: @GolezTrol: that doesn't work either; there are too many questions that cross programming languages. Software stacks are not so easily segregated either.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It was just a comment to clarify what I meant. If I would have had a complete water proof proposal, I would have put it in the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Then why do specific subsites like programming, dba, serverfault, game development etcetera have any right to exist? They also have overlap with the 'generic' questions on StackOverflow. I think that because those sites are more specialized, that they will attract more experienced users who are interested in the specific subject, leading to more and better answers. My reasoning is that the omnipresent and comprehensive scope of SO actually kanibalised those other SE sites. In a way, I'm trying to say: *"StackOverflow must die!"* but then making it sound a bit less evil. ;)

Comment: Let's say we have a C# only StackOverflow. C# is one of the most popular languages on the site, so the C# only StackOverflow is going to face similar issues, we'll segregate the crap making it even hard to control.

Comment: @GolezTrol: they go beyond programming too. They go into a wider subject; not just how do I code against the API or use the language, but also configuration, life cycle management, marketing, whathaveyou. Their scope of subjects is *different*. Hence the overlap with SO for some of these.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Rather than focusing on obstacles in the details of the plan, could you please try to discuss whether the issue I see is acutally an issue and whether the possible solution I described could be a solution, provided that we could define proper boundaries for each spin-off? On other words, could we keep it more meta/high level for now?

Comment: @GolezTrol: Well, those details is why splitting up SO into sub-communities is not going to work, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters When you discuss problems in your work (or wherever), do you also just pick a detail and kill the discussion by saying you don't know a solution to that? Or do you try to discuss the actual problem, brainstorm about possible solutions, and only after that talk about the details and viability of those solutions?

Comment: @GolezTrol If we come across a show stopper when brainstorming, we kill that idea, and pursue a different one, else we're just gonna be going in circles making no progress.

Comment: Well, if you think *"C# is too big"* is a such a show stopper that it renders the whole concept of Stack Overflow immutable then you probably won't make much progress anyway.

Comment: You clearly misunderstood my initial comment. Fragmenting the crap doesn't prevent it, it just makes it harder to manage. That, is a show stopper as far as this idea is concerned.

Comment: I'm of the opposite opinion.  I think it's already too fragmented.   I'd like to have one reputation on stack overflow.  Not have my rep divided over 3 different sites.   Should have one site with some customizable default filters.

Comment: Whole world is on it. Separating it as pro and learner has no use since pros often miss the basics too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think splitting Stack Overflow into smaller sub-sites would add overall value. It would probably have the opposite effect.

By nature, software development often encompasses multiple sub-subjects that overlap: PHP and MySQL, C++ and multithreading, Java and SSL, even [Java *and* JavaScript](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262693/372643).

Firstly, choosing the boundaries would be quite difficult. You could have a site for Tag A and Tag B, and another one for Tag C and Tag D, but where would you ask a question about Tag C and Tag C?

Secondly, even if we somehow agreed on some boundaries, this might actually increase the arguments about what belongs on a site and not another. I can't find the reference right now, but I seem to remember a few questions recently here on Meta requesting the migration of a question that was on-topic on another site. The idea was that it shouldn't necessarily be migrated out of Stack Overflow, since being on-topic somewhere else didn't mean it was off-topic here. (Practically, there is only a limited number of automatic migrations as it is.)

Thirdly, you could potentially miss out on the expertise of users who don't necessarily want to hang out on multiple site. A question that's apparently about C# could in fact have its root cause in the way that code is trying to make a SQL query, for example. Expecting SQL experts to be regulars of each sub-site that makes use of SQL could be a problem. (Of course, the problem can be reversed, you could have a question that seems to be able a SQL query that you would ask on DBA.SE, but it could turn out that what's causing the issue is the code calling it.)

Fourthly, the day you want to ask a question about Z, having gained reputation on X and Y, you couldn't make use of that reputation to place a bounty on your question (since you can't transfer reputation between sites). This also applies more generally to reputation-based privileges.

In addition, being exposed to questions about subjects you don't know anything about is generally a good thing for a developer, to gain some awareness of what's out there in terms of general programming knowledge.

Admittedly, there are relatively very few [Generalist badge holders](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist) (I'm in fact partly surprised you asked that question, since you're one of them), but this doesn't mean that developers are not interested in a multitude of subjects at once.

One negative aspect of having so many subjects is that some reviewers don't necessarily refrain on voting on questions that they don't understand, but people with more experience in the subject would. This seems to result in a few cases of questions closed as "unclear" or generally "off topic", when they weren't actually so bad. I don't think the solution to that problem is to split Stack Overflow into sub-subjects.

The multitude of subjects on Stack Overflow can feel a bit overwhelming, but people can filter by tags if necessary. Perhaps filtering systems could be improved, but I don't think splitting the site per subject would be beneficial.

I think the real problem comes from bad questions (general poor quality, non-constructive, vague, or give-me-the-code) not so much from the breadth of subjects (all software development related).

(I would in fact suggest to be more lenient in what's off-topic in terms of subject (I'm not talking about the other kinds of "off-topic"), more specifically to allow more [sysadmin type of questions, done within a development project, not suitable for Server Fault](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266612/372643): I'd trade any 10 poor questions we get here for 1 such reasonably asked question.)

As for splitting the site per level of competence, besides the fact that it's generally self-determined, there are downsides I've mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266579/372643):

> There are questions, even by beginners, that require a relatively good
>   degree of expertise in the field, from the start (at the very least to
>   approve or disapprove with existing answers).
>
> I remember seeing a case like this on SO a while back. I can't
>   remember the exact question, but it was about encrypting/hashing
>   passwords in PHP. Within 2 minutes, non-experts were pasting snippets
>   of code to try to answer the question (in a FGITW way), producing
>   answers that had the appearance to be correct and helpful (they got
>   rid of the problem and produced what looked like an "encrypted
>   result", i.e. gibberish). A few minutes later, someone more expert in
>   crypto (and with the relevant knowledge of the PHP API) produced a
>   detailed answer, not only giving a correct solution, but explaining
>   what was wrong with the other answers, and why they were insecure.
>
> I guess it's quite clear that if we split SO into beginner and
>   advanced, experts would probably not be much present on the beginner's
>   site. Hence, wrong ideas would self-perpetuate on the beginner's site.

This has also been discussed a few times (see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254381/372643) and its duplicates).

Comment: +1 Good points. I think it is true that some more questions will be on topic on multiple sites, although maybe that is not a bad thing. Regarding the division of experts; you've got a point there, but I think that experts would happily participate in two or three sites of their expertise, and feel their activities also get more exposure because it is a XYZ-experts website. But the coin could drop either way.

Comment: And it's true, I'm a generalist, so maybe it would not be in my personal best interest to split up SO, but then again, SO doesn't exist for my personal gain, so I though I should look past that. Anyway, thanks for your insights and your elaborate answer.

Comment: @GolezTrol Just as an example, I've been rather active on the [tag:ssl] tag here, I've also provided a number of answers on Security.SE and SF, but much fewer on SU and Webmasters.SE, all of which have an `ssl` tag. SO is the SE site I visit the most. I just can't monitor them all, nor do I want to. Splitting per language (presumably that would be one way of splitting per subject) would make it all more difficult. You also get the cases of issues when a C# client tries to talk to a Java server, or similar sort of overlaps on SO.

Comment: I'm voting this down for the simple reason that it is multiple arguments all rolled into one. I cannot upvote the one and downvote the other (and yes, I wish to downvote one). Multiple arguments -> multiple answers.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes It's an old discussion, but it might help if you said which argument you disagree with...

Answer (score 0):

> Would a solution like that be viable for the non-professional or not-necessarily-professional StackOverflow as well?

You should check the [technology section of Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/8/technology) to see what is already under proposal or approaching beta. There is nothing stopping you from starting the setup process for a new site - just go through the process at Area 51. Even if these sites get off the ground and make it to beta there will still be a certain amount of cross-over between them and Stack Overflow, so questions for them will still get asked and answered on SO, there's no guarantee they would get migrated.

As for segregating the beginners, there is already a proposal for the [Stack Overflow Academy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/72987/stack-overflow-academy) which you could support (**edit: the proposal has since been deleted**).

Comment: Stack Overflow academy isn't a place for beginners to ask their programming related questions.

Comment: @Joe Yeah I know that, but it's a useful sandpit for them to play in for a while.

Comment: I meant maybe it is a good idea to actually split up StackOverflow, rather than keep it and add spin-offs. Because it is so huge, people will often keep coming to StackOverflow with their questions, still 'polluting' it.

Comment: "Get rid of Stack Overflow" is definitely a nonstarter. Stackexchange isn't going to eliminate the cornerstone of their entire business. Feel free to make your own network of smaller programming site no one will use.

Comment: @Wooble Split up, *within* the StackExchange network. If my intention was to compete, I wouldn't need to ask here.