# Should there be a warning when a post is tagged with [java] and [javascript]?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-tips

Since [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) often ([though not always](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262693/javascript-java)) is different from [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), it might make sense to have a warning when both are used in the same question.  This would probably be similar to the warning with [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql):

> [image: SQL Tag Message]

It might look similar to this mock-up I made:

> [image: Java/JS Tag Message Mockup]

Does this seem like a good idea?

---

The reason why I am using red as the color is because that's the color of the [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) message.  The color is apparently temporary (If I remember correctly, it was cobbled together from available features and the color isn't yet changeable), but [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274897/can-the-tag-tips-be-in-a-non-critical-color) is about changing the color for it.  Just assume it is a more reasonable color than blatant error-message red.

---

Demos of what this would look like!

Red (`message-error`; `validation-error` on the bar):

```html
<link href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="position: relative;">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Tags</label>
    <input name="tagnames" tabindex="103" id="tagnames" style="display: none;" type="text" size="60" value="">
    <div class="tag-editor validation-error" style="width: 300px; height: 27px; opacity: 1;"><span><span class="post-tag">java<span title="remove this tag" class="delete-tag"></span></span>
      </span>
      <span class="post-tag">javascript<span title="remove this tag" class="delete-tag"></span></span>
      <input tabindex="103" style="width: 171px;" type="text" value=""><span></span>
    </div>
    <span class="edit-field-overlay">
at least one tag such as (sql .net html5), max 5 tags    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="message message-error message-dismissable" style="left: 311px; top: 42.23px; display: block; position: absolute; min-width: 270px; max-width: 270px;">
    <div class="message-inner message-tip message-tip-left-top">
      <div title="close this message (or hit Esc)" class="message-close">×</div>
      <div class="message-text" style="padding-right: 35px;">
        <ul>
          <li>You have both <span class="post-tag">java</span> and <span class="post-tag">javascript</span> tags on your post.
            <ul>
              <li>In most cases, only one of these two tags should be used, as they are for vastly different languages.</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Yellow <sub><sub><sup><sup>or ugly brown</sup></sup></sub></sub> (`message-warning`; `validation-warning` on the bar):

```html
<link href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="position: relative;">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Tags</label>
    <input name="tagnames" tabindex="103" id="tagnames" style="display: none;" type="text" size="60" value="">
    <div class="tag-editor validation-warning" style="width: 300px; height: 27px; opacity: 1;"><span><span class="post-tag">java<span title="remove this tag" class="delete-tag"></span></span>
      </span>
      <span class="post-tag">javascript<span title="remove this tag" class="delete-tag"></span></span>
      <input tabindex="103" style="width: 171px;" type="text" value=""><span></span>
    </div>
    <span class="edit-field-overlay">
at least one tag such as (sql .net html5), max 5 tags    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="message message-warning message-dismissable" style="left: 311px; top: 42.23px; display: block; position: absolute; min-width: 270px; max-width: 270px;">
    <div class="message-inner message-tip message-tip-left-top">
      <div title="close this message (or hit Esc)" class="message-close">×</div>
      <div class="message-text" style="padding-right: 35px;">
        <ul>
          <li>You have both <span class="post-tag">java</span> and <span class="post-tag">javascript</span> tags on your post.
            <ul>
              <li>In most cases, only one of these two tags should be used, as they are for vastly different languages.</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Blue (`message-info`, nothing on the bar as there is no `validation-info`)

```html
<link href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="position: relative;">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Tags</label>
    <input name="tagnames" tabindex="103" id="tagnames" style="display: none;" type="text" size="60" value="">
    <div class="tag-editor" style="width: 300px; height: 27px; opacity: 1;"><span><span class="post-tag">java<span title="remove this tag" class="delete-tag"></span></span>
      </span>
      <span class="post-tag">javascript<span title="remove this tag" class="delete-tag"></span></span>
      <input tabindex="103" style="width: 171px;" type="text" value=""><span></span>
    </div>
    <span class="edit-field-overlay">
at least one tag such as (sql .net html5), max 5 tags    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="message message-info message-dismissable" style="left: 311px; top: 42.23px; display: block; position: absolute; min-width: 270px; max-width: 270px;">
    <div class="message-inner message-tip message-tip-left-top">
      <div title="close this message (or hit Esc)" class="message-close">×</div>
      <div class="message-text" style="padding-right: 35px;">
        <ul>
          <li>You have both <span class="post-tag">java</span> and <span class="post-tag">javascript</span> tags on your post.
            <ul>
              <li>In most cases, only one of these two tags should be used, as they are for vastly different languages.</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think it's necessary and possibly setting a bad precedent. The community, from what I've seen, usually does a good job editing and commenting in these situations

Comment: That doesn't mean they actually enjoy doing the policing though. I can't see the harm in this.

Comment: It is possible that both tags may be appropriate, such as calling Java code in an applet from Javascript in a web page (yeah, nobody does that, but it's possible!).

Comment: @ChrisLaplante do any of us *enjoy* correcting new users *multiple times*? Maybe not but we aren't here just to have a great time. We can't create policies just because we don't enjoy doing a little work to keep the site clean. The harm is, where does it stop? And how can you do this efficiently? As pointed out in the question itself, sometimes they *are* both needed. I don't think posting a warning that one tag may not be needed will ensure the best/correct one will be used. This may just push people to delete the wrong tag when the community could have corrected it and set the user straight

Comment: @GregHewgill I did explicitly note that.  It's a notification; not a ban.  Another good example would be (EG) [Rhino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_(JavaScript_engine)).  Just looking at the [tags that are categorized with both](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+javascript), there are examples.  But it's a simple mistake for people to use them incorrectly, so a warning is a good idea.

Comment: In my experience, the Java and JavaScript tags are used together legitimately more often than not, which is surprising, but there are many technologies and methodologies that use them both.

Comment: In fact, there are [currently 8,509 non-closed questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bjavascript%5D+closed%3Ano) tagged with both tags. That's even more than some language tags, such as [tag:closure].

Comment: I see no harm in a friendly warning message.

Comment: Red isn't friendly.

Comment: @Doorknob closure isn't a language, Clojure is. It still has less than 8509 questions, but not by as much.

Comment: Regardless of whether this is a request requiring attention, note that (something I didn't realize until I gained the privilege) [10K users can "quick edit" tags](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) for a question, which means at 10K+ it's fairly easy to correct this problem.

Comment: @resueman Whoops, yeah, that was a typo. But you get the point.

Comment: @OrangeDog I agree; but from what I know the feature used with SQL was quickly set up and the color can't be customized yet.  I think a different color would be nice as well.  [See this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274897/can-the-tag-tips-be-in-a-non-critical-color).

Comment: askers who use both tags should see popup [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5184356/839601)

Comment: @OrangeDog there are alternate styles available that use a warning colour instead of red, see [my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274966/57475)

Comment: This would be _great_ with [tag:C] and [tag:C++]!

Comment: I'd like to point out that [GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+javascript+gwt) actually uses both Java and JavaScript, even in the same class, and is a decent portion of Java/JavaScript questions. A lot of users end up using all three tags to indicate coverage.

Comment: @Compass I've already noted in the post that there are many cases of the tags making sense together, but it is easy for new people to mess it up.  It's corrected quickly, but it still is possible to mess up.  And one wouldn't be blocked from submitting them; it would just notify.

Comment: @Pokechu22 I know. I felt it worth mentioning that there is actually a practical, real-world language where you will literally see Java and JavaScript side by side.

Comment: If the user doesn't understand the difference between java and javascript, the warning suggested would likely just cause more confusion.

Comment: @matsjoyce if you force people to choose between `c` and `c++` instead of choosing both, how often do you think they'll chose the correct one?

Comment: @SamIam Well, whenever someone posts question with the tags [tag:c] and [tag:c++], usually (IME) the first comment is choose one or the other, so letting the system do that automatically may speed things up.

Comment: `Please do this`

Answer (score 40):

I understand your point but I don't think it is such a big issue that it needs to be fixed.

In my opinion:

- there are many situations where one may legitimately use both tags
- when a user tags a question with both tags by error the wrong tag is generally removed by editors within 5 minutes because [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) have a large audience
- users who use both tags by mistake are often new to the site and I have the feeling that they are statistically less likely to read every single message they get when posting a question - too much information can become counter-productive.

Comment: That is true. They could easily read the tag description that says `Use this tag for questions referring to Java programming...` and `Use this tag for questions regarding ECMAScript and its various dialects/implementations (excluding ActionScript)...` but they don't.

Comment: Not only that, but if a user erroneously tags a question with both Java and JavaScript where only one is applicable, it's probably because they don't know the difference - and they should. What better way to learn the difference than to be told by someone on SO? I've learned many valuable pieces of information that way. I wouldn't want us to limit people's exposure by catching their mistakes before they're made.

Comment: Look at the downvotes I got by suggesting the very same thing: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265601/allow-for-tag-antonyms/265741#265741 -- MSO change of heart?

Comment: @ChrisBaker that's what you get for being ahead of the curve!

Answer (score 22):

No. [There are many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+javascript?sort=votes) questions that use both tags legitimately (from a quick scan, mostly about comparing the languages or about accessing a Java server from a JavaScript script).

The more common problem that askers confuse JavaScript with Java would not really be solved by this, as those questions typically have only one (the wrong) tag on them - if OP is using both, he usually knows the difference.

Incorrect usages are quite fast fixed by the community.