# Failed known-bad audit after flagging because I'm Done was not enabled

Tags: bug, status-completed, disputed-review-audits, first-post-review

I recently [reviewed a post where I flagged a post as Not an Answer](//stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/12940977). Now usually the "I'm Done" button is highlighted after I flag or if it's a test it automatically shows the result but this time the "I'm Done" button wasn't available to click (still greyed even after flagging).

Since it wasn't available and I had already flagged it, I clicked "No Action Needed". Now it popped that it was a test and I should have flagged it. 
I DID flag but nothing happened and now the system has banned me from reviewing for a month.

Is there any way to resolve this? I did flag the answer but still facing a ban. I feel a little sad about it honestly.

EDIT - Other users facing the same issue today [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327615/review-audit-failed-despite-flagging-the-answer-properly?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327587/this-answer-has-already-been-deleted-when-attempting-to-flag-during-review?noredirect=1&lq=1). Bug maybe ?

**Gimby has mentioned the <s>right</s> situation-appropriate answer** that it is better to skip/leave the question as is rather than marking it.
Like Will said, I too thought No Action Needed was appropriate as I had flagged it already but it clearly wasn't.
What I faced could be a bug in SO or maybe my corporate firewall issues or plainly my bad luck.

I'll get back to reviewing after a month I guess.

EDIT 2 -

Turns out it was bug after all. Kudos to SO team for fixing it so quickly !

Comment: To be banned for a month you have to have previously been banned for 2 days, carried on regardless, then be banned for 7 days and carried on regardless, now that you're up to a month don't you think it might be time to consider how you are reviewing and be more careful. Your review ban is the accumulation of many bad reviews, not just this straw that broke the camel's back.

Comment: Next time, choose to skip the review if you can't pick the option you think is right, or you're uncertain. in this case "no action needed" was really obviously the wrong choice and you knew it - so skip the review and report the incident in meta to learn the truth before its too late.

Comment: @RobertLongson I am not bothered about the duration of ban or even the ban itself. But for the reason why it had happened even when I had flagged the answer sincerely. I already know 30 day ban is followed by 7 days followed by 2 days. That is not what I am questioning or even pointing at.

Comment: @Gimby Yep. I learnt the hardway. Better to skip it or rather close the close the window without marking it at all. :)

Comment: @RobertLongson, I think the point was that he correctly identified a bad audit and wasn't correctly recognized for having successfully handling the bad answer. For all we know his behavior has changed for the better. Hence his flag.

Comment: @ouflak time will tell I guess.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm sure it wasn't my (or anyone's) behaviour which triggered the incorrect audit. Let us not sway away from the original question - Why was the button still gray even after flagging? Perhaps it could be a bug or connectivity issue with people who are behind several firewalls (like me).

Comment: This issue has also happened to me:
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327587/

Comment: @Gimby *"no action needed" was really obviously the wrong choice and you knew it* meh, I dunno.  If one flags the question, is there really any further action needed?  It's reasonable to think so.  Also, if you hit the skip button, does it also undo the flag?  You're skipping the review, and during the review you flagged a post, does that also skip the flag?  Unless you're versed in how the review system works, you could easily make the wrong decision.  Like OP.

Comment: @Will I fully agree it is easy to misunderstand and that there is a great need to be well-versed in the review system before you go full-tilt in it.

Comment: *Next time, choose to skip the review if you can't pick the option you think is right...skip the review and report the incident in meta* - @Gimby - This should probably be the posted answer.

Comment: [Here is another victim](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327615/review-audit-failed-despite-flagging-the-answer-properly#327615) from today. Has something been changed in the review queues lately?

Comment: @gnat That wasn't the best duplicate at the time, but I've amended the last section to handle this case a bit more explicitly.

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Comment: We've seen an uptick in the number of complaints about review audits and we're looking into it to see what's going on.

Comment: @bluefeet I just found this through a [migrated question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281080/why-did-flagging-as-very-low-quality-result-in-audit-failure) from Server Fault Meta when I was annoyed that a review did not accept my flagging as acceptable. I don't recall this behavior previously, but one big difference is the review answer was so bad, there was really no point even leaving a comment or down-voting, as I knew it would be deleted by first mod to see it.

Comment: We've found the source of the problem. Just need a fix.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So this was my fault - I moved some code around when I added a [moderator feature for flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309732/provide-context-specific-warnings-at-time-of-flagging-for-incorrect-flag-use/327895#327895) and broke flagging posts during an Audit in the process by removing some JavaScript that intercepts flags and makes sure the "I'm Done" button is activated.

I just pushed a new build that has the functionality restored, Audits should now work properly again.

Apologies for that.

Comment: Now write some php as penance!

Comment: *You* were working on *that feature*? *Awesome.*

Comment: Does this mean my ban will be removed since it was a bug?

Comment: I think that is fair to assume @PirateX

Comment: @PirateX your ban is lifted now.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 17):

This is a bug and [they are working on fixing it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281080/why-did-flagging-as-very-low-quality-result-in-audit-failure/281162?noredirect=1#comment913313_281162).

It seems to be happening to a lot of people (everyone), including me:

> [image: Me too!]

---

I tried to hack the HTML, but clicking the button does nothing:

> [image: hax]

My guess is that the error message means that no action registered, meaning that you might as well as not touched the flag button at all.*

Now, I could just "Skip", but that's not how queues work. The entire point of having these things is to bring potential problems to the attention of those who moderate.

And audits need to be able to be passed. In this case, I ended up trying to comment (I suspect that down voting would be good too) and I passed:

> [image: Yay!]

In the meantime, until this is fixed, consider trying to leave comments (bonus points if those comments mention this bug!).

---

* Most flags, most notably VLQ and NAA fail because the post is deleted. Moderator flags do not fail, but they don't work right either. Please don't use mod flags if you encounter this bug, since it will actually go through [for real.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327751/6083675)

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways to handle this case. The first is that any post that's worth flagging is almost always worth downvoting, so if you're unsure, try downvoting. Even if the post has been deleted and is being used as an audit, this will pass the audit, and if it hasn't and isn't, you can work with it. (It will probably show a message telling you that the post has been deleted, in this case.)

The second is that if you can't take the action you know the post needs — for any reason — don't click <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd>. It *does* need an action, but you just aren't able to take that action. Instead, click <kbd>Skip</kbd>, which is always a correct choice, and will never cause you to fail an audit.

Comment: What if you're out of votes?

Comment: @Will: See my last paragraph for the ultimate fallback that will always work.

Comment: @Will if you're out of votes an obvious approach would be to click no action needed on any sh!t you stumble upon. Let it fly through, just keep that fancy number of your reviews growing

Comment: @NathanTuggy the ultimate fallback is to not review. I use that every day.

Comment: My goal in reviewing is to help the site. If not, why would I be out of votes? I clicked No Action Needed because I had literally already performed the action--I flagged the post.

Comment: @Will you can't review first post without votes. This is a bug, still.