# This answer has already been deleted, when attempting to flag during review

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

I was doing reviews and came across this one here:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/12942319

Initially, I attempted to flag it as a low quality, as it was a link only answer, but was told I could not as it had already been deleted. I then stupidly clicked on *No Action Needed*, as since it had already been deleted, it had been dealt with.

Afterwards I get greeted with the failed audit review and told I should have learnt from my mistake. I understand I shouldn't have clicked  *No Action Needed*, but why did it not allow me to flag it as low quality and then suggest I passed the audit? Did I catch it at a bad time?

Comment: This seems related to [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327580/failed-known-bad-audit-after-flagging-because-im-done-was-not-enabled)...

Comment: I faced the exact issue today. I raised a question here in Meta (which Glorfindel has linked) but the votes and comments suggest that it was my bad audit history and behaviour that caused it. Perhaps you could share your issue, since you don't have a bad audit history like me. You'll get an objective response.

Comment: @PirateX well, your audit history was not good.  However, you can have a lousy audit history and still hit a bad audit/corner case bug/confusing outcome with an unclear path forward.

Comment: @Will I share the same view, but it seems the users of SO do not. See the link Glorfindel shared.

Comment: @PirateX your question has 13 upvotes at this time.  Believe me, if more people disagreed, you'd be sitting at **-13** or less.  Audits are ... touchy.  They aren't the best at the good times.  Clicking on certain things is an autofail.  Issues like you experienced.  Poorly (randomly!) chosen audit candidates...  SE needs to do an overhaul and rethink some of the design points in audits.  Understand, people are saying your autoban's ***length*** was warranted due to your history, but the circumstances that resulted in your failing the audit are specious, at best imho. Other's HO as well.

Comment: @Draken [I think you were supposed to click 'Skip' instead](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327628/2693146).

Comment: Fixed: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327896

Answer (score -3):

Agree completely with @Will. The snarky messages upon audit failures have completely turned me off on such efforts. He was addressing a new user, but that doesn't describe me. I suppose a real answer would be to knuckle under and do what the ubermods want. But I'm getting the message that SO curators only want reviewers that completely agree with their limited set of definitions of "rightness. They are instead pissing of people and increasing the load on the more tolerant reviewers. Not good reviewer relations.