# Review audit failed despite flagging the answer properly

Tags: discussion, bug, review-audits

After reviewing a first post, I flagged it as very low quality and hit next, but the system reported it as review audit failed. (Despite being correct)

Now I can no longer review as it's saying I've made too many incorrect reviews and sites the question I reviewed [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/12947605).

I don't really care about having to wait 2 days, but thought I would bring it up as that seems like a bug to me. There doesn't seem to be a way I can prove I flagged it, as flags on audits don't seem to be saved under questions/answers you've flagged.

I don't think I misclicked either, but even if I did, I flagged it properly. (I'm 100% sure I flagged it) I would assume the system would count that as an audit pass as I performed the correct action.

**Edit: I flagged it very low quality**

Comment: You failed because that answer was considered being a comment. The answer is deleted meanwhile. So flagging "No action needed" was not the right action.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I didn't flag no action needed, I flagged very low quality

Comment: @JeremyW Well, may be you have misclicked the button. The review clearly says _"Jeremy W reviewed this 16 mins ago: No Action Needed
  Next"_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ which I stated in the question that even if I had, I definitely flagged it properly. I don't think I did though.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, as I pressed the CORRECT button AND flagged it

Comment: @JeremyW The issue in the linked duplicate is exactly the same as yours- They _flagged_ the audit post and it didn't register as a pass. It didn't register at all. They clicked the wrong button after that, because the "I'm Done" button didn't enable. In your case, the audit says you clicked "No Action Needed", which may have been a misclick _after_ you correctly flagged the post and it didn't register.

Comment: @Kendra Lol, I was saying I didn't hit the wrong button, as in I hit the correct button. But fair enough, doesn't look like this is that important.

Comment: Fixed: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327896