# Rework the definition of the term 'JavaScript' on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, tags

The definition of JavaScript given by Stack Overflow when you click on its tag is:

> JavaScript (not to be confused with Java) is a high-level, dynamic, multi-paradigm, object-oriented, prototype-based, weakly-typed language used for both client-side and server-side scripting. Its primary use is in rendering and manipulating of web pages. Use this tag for questions regarding ECMAScript and its various dialects/implementations (excluding ActionScript and Google-Apps-Script).

But is it vital to specify that JavaScript should not be confused with Java just because the terms are similar?

As if we had to specify that Iceland should not be confused with the word ice.

Am I the only one wondering why "(not to be confused with Java)" is in the definition?

Comment: You bet it's needed. To this day people confuse Java and JavaScript frequently.

Comment: Often users tag both because they get them confused. I'd say it's needed.

Comment: Related: ["JavaScript != Java"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262693/javascript-java) . One of the most common types of comment I see (usually after either the [java] or [javascript] tag has been removed from a question) are those informing people that they shouldn't tag their JavaScript question with [java] and vice versa. That the two are related is a very common misconception in Stack Overflow questions. Don't know how much of this is prevented by that warning, but it can't hurt.

Comment: Wait... aren't they the same thing?

Comment: (For OP: The comment above is sarcastic. Such comments are seen a lot on meta site. Don't do this on main)

Comment: Frequently doesn't explain how often it really happens. Multiple times a day is more accurate, and as a JS tag watcher, and a Java tag ignorer, it's frustrating to see it still occurring so often.

Comment: Worth mentioning that phrase was added [in revision 30](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3624960/30) in 2013 while the tag first excerpt was created in 2010. Currently revision 56 is shown so 26 editors didn't bother to remove it.

Comment: Actually we do tend to have to clarify that Iceland != ice; in fact, Iceland is largely green, whereas its neighbor, Greenland, is largely ice, leading to this unfortunate assumption that each one is the opposite type (in general) of place.

Comment: @SterlingArcher is absolutely correct. It's not unusual yo see this both tags when only one is needed a dozen times or so a day. Not *for the entire day* in total, for me that's just when I'm looking at newest in `javascript` which I do on and off for *at most* 10 hours a day. The fact that OP doesn't see these questions speaks volumes for me and everybody else on both the `javascript` and `java` tags who make constant edits to keep the separation *despite* there being a clear disclaimer on both tags.

Comment: Car is to carpet as Java is to JavaScript.

Answer (score 21):

Sadly, this is a common enough mistake since the first release of the language.

Although nowadays the confusion is much less likely to occur, particularly with a with a technical audience, there is no harm in keeping that disclaimer there.

Why should we remove it? What would we gain by that?

Comment: Ok why not for **very very very** beginner from stackoverflow. 99.99% know the difference but for the others they will be quickly informed by the community. By reading a definition I hope to find what I'm looking for as quickly as possible, but in this case a good part of the **first** sentence tells me only secondary things. Why not specify this later in the definition?

Comment: Frankly, I fail to see your point. The users most likely to need to read about what Javascript is are those that could benefit the most from the disclaimer. And those that do not need the disclaimer are less likely to need to read the tag info in the first place.

Comment: Ok well you are right

Comment: It’s not just beginners, sadly. @johann

Answer (score 1):

> But is it vital to specify that JavaScript should not be confused with Java just because the terms are similar?

Often when I am conversing with users entering programming, especially those in the realm of only needing small amounts of it to work with their other projects (such as engineers who only need a little bit of code to read a sensor), I still find them not understanding the difference.

While it isn't exactly that problematic, I think it is still important to keep this reminder there, especially with the current prominence of engineers entering programming through Python.

Comment: I don't understand that last sentence. Are you taking a stab at Python developers for not knowing about Java[Script]? Or are you just promoting Python? If so, can I name drop some others as well?

Comment: @rene - No, I am saying that a lot of engineers (aerospace, electrical, mechanical, etc.) use Python with Raspberry Pi to construct sensing equipment. Often, they are not programmers so I definitely wouldn't refer to them as developers if they are just beginning engineers. Clearly there are many experienced Python developers who know the difference, and are very knowledgeable in general about programming and developing. I only mention Python because of its prevalence.